# What are the effects of exceptions on performance in Java?

Tags: java, performance, exception

Question:  Is exception handling in Java actually slow?

Conventional wisdom, as well as a lot of Google results, says that exceptional logic shouldn't be used for normal program flow in Java.  Two reasons are usually given,

1. it is really slow - even an order of magnitude slower than regular code (the reasons given vary),

and

2. it is messy because people expect only errors to be handled in exceptional code.

This question is about #1.

As an example, [this page](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/exceptions/03exceptions.html) describes Java exception handling as "very slow" and relates the slowness to the creation of the exception message string - "this string is then used in creating the exception object that is thrown. This is not fast."  The article [Effective Exception Handling in Java](http://adtmag.com/articles/2000/08/22/effective-exception-handling-in-java.aspx) says that "the reason for this is due to the object creation aspect of exception handling, which thereby makes throwing exceptions inherently slow".  Another reason out there is that the stack trace generation is what slows it down.

My testing (using Java 1.6.0_07, Java HotSpot 10.0, on 32 bit Linux), indicates that exception handling is no slower than regular code.  I tried running a method in a loop that executes some code.  At the end of the method, I use a boolean to indicate whether to *return* or *throw*.  This way the actual processing is the same. I tried running the methods in different orders and averaging my test times, thinking it may have been the JVM warming up.  In all my tests, the throw was at least as fast as the return, if not faster (up to 3.1% faster).  I am completely open to the possibility that my tests were wrong, but I haven't seen anything out there in the way of the code sample, test comparisons, or results in the last year or two that show exception handling in Java to actually be slow.

What leads me down this path was an API I needed to use that threw exceptions as part of normal control logic.  I wanted to correct them in their usage, but now I may not be able to.  Will I instead have to praise them on their forward thinking?

In the paper [Efficient Java exception handling in just-in-time compilation](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=337453), the authors suggest that the presence of exception handlers alone, even if no exceptions are thrown, is enough to prevent the JIT compiler from optimizing the code properly, thus slowing it down.  I haven't tested this theory yet.

Comment: I know you were't asking about 2), but you really should recognize that using an exception for program flow is no better than using GOTOs.  Some people defend gotos, some people would defend what you are talking about, but if you ask someone who has implemented and maintained either for a period of time, they will tell you that both are poor hard to maintain design practices (and will probably curse the name of the person who thought they were smart enough to make the decision to use them).

Comment: Bill, claiming that using exceptions for program flow is no better than using GOTOs is no better than claiming that using conditionals and loops for program flow is no better than using GOTOs. It's a red herring. Explain yourself. Exceptions can and are used effectively for program flow in other languages. Idiomatic Python code uses exceptions regularly, for instance. I can and have maintained code that uses exceptions in this way (not Java though), and I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with it.

Comment: Note that some web frameworks use Exceptions as a convenient way to redirect - e.g. Wicket's [RestartResponseException](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/RestartResponseException.html). It happens just few times per request, usually not, and I can hardly imagine more convenient way in a Java-oriented component framework.

Comment: @mmalone using Exceptions for normal control flow is a bad idea in Java because *the paradigm choice was done that way*. Read Bloch EJ2 - he clearly states that, quote, (Item 57) `exceptions are, as their name implies, to be used only for exceptional conditions; they should never be used for ordinary control flow` - giving complete and extensive explanation as to why. And he was the guy who *wrote* Java lib. Therefore, he's the one to define classes' API contract. /agree Bill K on this one.

Comment: @OndraŽižka  If some framework does this (use Exceptions in non-exceptional condition), it's flawed and broken by design, breaking the language's Exception class contract. Just because some people write lousy code doesn't make it less lousy.

Comment: btw, it worries me much that mmalone's comment got so many upvotes despite saying "I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with it"... While I understand the request for reference he did (although the reference is quite obvious in this case), it saddens me to see people agreeing with it, as it only highlights how severely SO "community quality assurance" deteriorated over time to me.

Comment: None other than the creator of stackoverflow.com is on record saying exceptions are worse than GOTOs: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html

Comment: None other than the creator of stackoverflow.com is wrong about exceptions.  The golden rule of software development is never make the simple complex and unwieldy.  

He writes: "It is true that what should be a simple 3 line program often blossoms to 48 lines when you put in good error checking, but that's life, ..."

This is a search for purity, not simplicity.

Comment: One of the funny things about Java--we concern ourselves with something like the performance of a try/catch which slows Java by a HUGE factor--but it would still be faster than nearly any other language out there (aside from the C's and a few esoteric ones like Fortran!?!).  Even if you used exceptions heavily you wouldn't slow down to the speed of Python; and as for Ruby???  Not even if every single statement was somehow exception-based could you get THAT slow.  On the other hand, Exceptions lead to hard to follow code and are generally a PITA, best to avoid wherever possible.

Comment: In the old days, populating the stacktrace was quite slow. To my understanding this improved drastically around java 5-6-ish

Comment: OP should runs some after pushing a thousand frames to the stack, so the affects of a bigger stacktrace are more apparent.

Comment: The question is about exception 'handling', where the alternative is very often a crash. You can't get much slower than stopped. If you are thinking of using exceptions as a flow-control element, as Bill K. suggested, just make sure that nobody else has to maintain the code...

Answer (score 373, accepted):

It depends how exceptions are implemented. The simplest way is using setjmp and longjmp. That means all registers of the CPU are written to the stack (which already takes some time) and possibly some other data needs to be created... all this already happens in the try statement. The throw statement needs to unwind the stack and restore the values of all registers (and possible other values in the VM). So try and throw are equally slow, and that is pretty slow, however if no exception is thrown, exiting the try block takes no time whatsoever in most cases (as everything is put on the stack which cleans up automatically if the method exists).

Sun and others recognized, that this is possibly suboptimal and of course VMs get faster and faster over the time. There is another way to implement exceptions, which makes try itself lightning fast (actually nothing happens for try at all in general - everything that needs to happen is already done when the class is loaded by the VM) and it makes throw not quite as slow. I don't know which JVM uses this new, better technique...

...but are you writing in Java so your code later on only runs on one JVM on one specific system? Since if it may ever run on any other platform or any other JVM version (possibly of any other vendor), who says they also use the fast implementation? The fast one is more complicated than the slow one and not easily possible on all systems. You want to stay portable? Then don't rely on exceptions being fast.

It also makes a big difference what you do within a try block. If you open a try block and never call any method from within this try block, the try block will be ultra fast, as the JIT can then actually treat a throw like a simple goto. It neither needs to save stack-state nor does it need to unwind the stack if an exception is thrown (it only needs to jump to the catch handlers). However, this is not what you usually do. Usually you open a try block and then call a method that might throw an exception, right? And even if you just use the try block within your method, what kind of method will this be, that does not call any other method? Will it just calculate a number? Then what for do you need exceptions? There are much more elegant ways to regulate program flow. For pretty much anything else but simple math, you will have to call an external method and this already destroys the advantage of a local try block.

See the following test code:

```
public class Test {
    int value;


    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void reset() {
        value = 0;
    }

    // Calculates without exception
    public void method1(int i) {
        value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
        // Will never be true
        if ((i & 0xFFFFFFF) == 1000000000) {
            System.out.println("You'll never see this!");
        }
    }

    // Could in theory throw one, but never will
    public void method2(int i) throws Exception {
        value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
        // Will never be true
        if ((i & 0xFFFFFFF) == 1000000000) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    // This one will regularly throw one
    public void method3(int i) throws Exception {
        value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
        // i & 1 is equally fast to calculate as i & 0xFFFFFFF; it is both
        // an AND operation between two integers. The size of the number plays
        // no role. AND on 32 BIT always ANDs all 32 bits
        if ((i & 0x1) == 1) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        long l;
        Test t = new Test();

        l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        t.reset();
        for (i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
            t.method1(i);
        }
        l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
        System.out.println(
            "method1 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.getValue()
        );

        l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        t.reset();
        for (i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
            try {
                t.method2(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("You'll never see this!");
            }
        }
        l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
        System.out.println(
            "method2 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.getValue()
        );

        l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        t.reset();
        for (i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
            try {
                t.method3(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Do nothing here, as we will get here
            }
        }
        l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
        System.out.println(
            "method3 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.getValue()
        );
    }
}
```

Result:

```
method1 took 972 ms, result was 2
method2 took 1003 ms, result was 2
method3 took 66716 ms, result was 2
```

The slowdown from the try block is too small to rule out confounding factors such as background processes. But the catch block killed everything and made it 66 times slower!

As I said, the result will not be that bad if you put try/catch and throw all within the same method (method3), but this is a special JIT optimization I would not rely upon. And even when using this optimization, the throw is still pretty slow. So I don't know what you are trying to do here, but there is definitely a better way of doing it than using try/catch/throw.

Comment: great question and response, thanks John & Mecki! I inherited a code that does try-catch to any method (including setter/getter that simply return the value of a property) and was checking some more details on performance implications of such. The question and answer gave me full details on it ;). Best, stef.

Comment: @Mecki How is that your peformance is affected so high when JDK Hotspot should be caching these exceptions. http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue187.html Did you disable this option to run your tests?

Comment: Ahh after long time of debugging, I think when the code throws a new exception via `throw new Exception()` JDK will not cache it. But if Java throws it, for example `((Object)null).getClass()` then java will cache it.

Comment: In fairness there should be a version of the routine that creates an object (perhaps an exception) without throwing anything, to see how much of the performance difference is simply object creation.

Comment: (I've posted results of such a test below.)

Comment: Great answer but I'd just like to add that as far as I know, System.nanoTime() should be used for measuring performance, not System.currentTimeMillis().

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg `nanoTime()` requires Java 1.5 and I had only Java 1.4 available on the system I used for writing the code above. Also it doesn't play a huge role in practice. The only difference between the two is that one is nanosecond the other one milliseconds and that `nanoTime` is not influenced by clock manipulations (which are irrelevant, unless you or system process modifies the system clock exactly the moment the test code is running). Generally you are right, though, `nanoTime` is of course the better choice.

Comment: It really should be noted that your test is an extreme case.  You show a very small performance hit for code with a `try` block, but no `throw`.  Your `throw` test is throwing exceptions **50% of the time** it goes through the `try`.  That's clearly a situation where the failure is not *exceptional*.  Cutting that down to only 10% massively cuts the performance hit. The problem with this kind of test is that it encourages people to stop using exceptions altogether.  Using exceptions, for exceptional case handling, performs vastly better than what your test shows.

Comment: @Nate First of all, I said very clearly that all this depends on how exceptions are implemented. I was just testing ONE specific implementation, yet there are plenty and Oracle may choose an entirely different one with every release. Second, if exceptions are only exceptional, what they usually are, of course the impact is smaller, this is so obvious, that I really don't think one has to point it out explicitly and thus I cannot understand your point here at all. And third, exception overuse it bad, everyone agrees on that, so using them with a lot of care is a very good thing.

Comment: Mecki is right. The question was about comparing relative speed between regular control flow (a return statement) and exceptions. If anything, exceptions should be thrown 100% of the time, and not only 50%. Which means that we could be talking of code 132 times slower!

Comment: IMO one more comparison could be interesting "throw new Exception()" vs. "new Exception()", this way we can measure "throw" operation itself, rather than mixing it with "new Exception()" all the time. WDYT?

Comment: @Mecki Sorry but could you clarify your response a little bit more? I don't understand how come method 3 is so much slower. When you call a method that calls another method, it uses a stack for keeping track of the calls regardless if it's inside a try/catch, right? So what makes being inside try/catch slower? Thanks.

Comment: @Glide There are two ways to implement `try/catch`. Either `try` saves the whole processing state of a thread and if an exception is thrown that states is restored before `catch` is performed, this makes `try` slow (regardless if an exception is ever thrown or not) but `catch` will be not so slow. Or `try` only records a `catch` handler and the `catch` handler finds out what operations it must undo (think of a roll back), that makes `try` very fast, yet `catch` very slow (however `catch` is only ever executed if an exception is really thrown). Sorry, would need to write a book for all details.

Comment: @Glide A throw is not like a clean `return`. It leaves a method somewhere in the middle of the body, maybe even in the middle of an operation (that has so far completed only by 50%) and the `catch` block may be 20 stack frames upwards (a method has a `try` block, calling method1, which calls method2, which calls mehtod3, ..., and in method20 in the middle of an operation an exception is thrown). The stack must be unwind 20 frames upwards, all unfinished operations must be undone (operations must not be half done) and the CPU registers need to be in a clean state. This all consumes time.

Comment: You should also try testing it when throwing exceptions without stack traces

Comment: on jdk 1.8.0_181 I get these results showing that performance has improved:
method1 took 928 ms, result was 2 | 
method2 took 1098 ms, result was 2 | 
method3 took 26366 ms, result was 2

Comment: On higher Java versions, this benchmark is flawed, and does not warm up the code.  If you add a loop around the code in main to run the benchmark multiple times, there is no significant difference in any of the solutions.

Comment: @john16384 If I add a loop around `main` and run the test 3 times with Java 8, I get three times the same results and three times it is much slower when the exception is thrown, so I cannot confirm your claim. The only thing that has changed is that `try` has no speed penalty anymore but as I also explained in my answer, that depends on how exceptions are implemented. It is possible to implement `try` in a way that no additional code has to be executed unless an exception is actually thrown but therefore this implementation makes throw more expensive then the alternatives.

Comment: @Mecki See this answer for what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66320622/1262865 -- also some more complicated testing (where I'm using an Exception to flag a special case) shows similar behavior: a static (reused) exception which is always caught performs exactly the same as a "special" value (`null`).  A non-static one performs about 6x worse.

Comment: For an even more elaborated analysis, see Shipilёv’s [The Exceptional Performance of Lil' Exception](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/)

Answer (score 290):

FYI, I extended the experiment that Mecki did:

```
method1 took 1733 ms, result was 2
method2 took 1248 ms, result was 2
method3 took 83997 ms, result was 2
method4 took 1692 ms, result was 2
method5 took 60946 ms, result was 2
method6 took 25746 ms, result was 2
```

The first 3 are the same as Mecki's (my laptop is obviously slower).

method4 is identical to method3 except that it creates a `new Integer(1)` rather than doing `throw new Exception()`.

method5 is like method3 except that it creates the `new Exception()` without throwing it.

method6 is like method3 except that it throws a pre-created exception (an instance variable) rather than creating a new one.

In Java much of the expense of throwing an exception is the time spent gathering the stack trace, which occurs when the exception object is created.  The actual cost of throwing the exception, while large, is considerably less than the cost of creating the exception.

Comment: +1 Your answer addresses the core issue - the time taken to unwind the and trace the stack, and secondarily the throwing of the error. I would have selected this as the final answer.

Comment: nice.  ~70% creating the exception, ~30% throwing it.  good info.

Comment: Similar question, how much extra overhead is there in catching an exception, re-throwing it, and catching it again? Thanks.

Comment: @Basil - You should be able to figure that out from the above numbers.

Comment: This may be implementation specific.  What version of Java was used for these benchmarks?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - What I have now is java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode).  No telling what I had 5+ years ago.  But the code is shown above, in Mecki's post.  You can try it yourself.

Comment: @HotLicks and this is exactly why it is important to tell which version of Java was used in the post

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - So have you tried it yourself?  The only way to bypass the performance bottleneck would be to somehow delay the execution of most of `new Exception()`, while still assuring that the stack info is not lost in the interim.  Doing this would likely be more expensive than the straight-forward approach, for the case where the exception is actually signaled.

Comment: We can remark that in standard code, creating and throwing exceptions occurs in rare cases (at runtime I mean), if it is not the case, either runtime conditions are very bad, or the design is itself the problem; in both cases performances are not a concern...

Answer (score 91):

Aleksey Shipilëv did a [very thorough analysis](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/) in which he benchmarks Java exceptions under various combinations of conditions:

- Newly created exceptions vs pre-created exceptions
- Stack trace enabled vs disabled
- Stack trace requested vs never requested
- Caught at the top level vs rethrown at every level vs chained/wrapped at every level
- Various levels of Java call stack depth
- No inlining optimizations vs extreme inlining vs default settings
- User-defined fields read vs not read

He also compares them to the performance of checking an error code at various levels of error frequency.

The conclusions (quoted verbatim from his post) were:

1. **Truly exceptional exceptions are beautifully performant.** If you use them as designed, and only communicate the truly exceptional cases among the overwhelmingly large number of non-exceptional cases handled by regular code, then using exceptions is the performance win.
2. The performance costs of exceptions have two major components: **stack trace construction** when Exception is instantiated and **stack unwinding** during Exception throw.
3. **Stack trace construction costs are proportional to stack depth** at the moment of exception instantiation. That is already bad because who on Earth knows the stack depth at which this throwing method would be called? Even if you turn off the stack trace generation and/or cache the exceptions, you can only get rid of this part of the performance cost.
4. **Stack unwinding costs depend on how lucky we are with bringing the exception handler closer in the compiled code.** Carefully structuring the code to avoid deep exception handlers lookup is probably helping us get luckier.
5. **Should we eliminate both effects, the performance cost of exceptions is that of the local branch.** No matter how beautiful it sounds, that does not mean you should use Exceptions as the usual control flow, because in that case **you are at the mercy of optimizing compiler!** You should only use them in truly exceptional cases, where the exception frequency **amortizes** the possible unlucky cost of raising the actual exception.
6. The optimistic rule-of-thumb seems to be **10^-4** frequency for exceptions is exceptional enough. That, of course, depends on the heavy-weights of the exceptions themselves, the exact actions taken in exception handlers, etc.

The upshot is that when an exception isn't thrown, you don't pay a cost, so when the exceptional condition is sufficiently rare exception handling is faster than using an `if` every time. The full post is very much worth a read.

Answer (score 44):

My answer, unfortunately, is just too long to post here. So let me summarize here and refer you to http://www.fuwjax.com/how-slow-are-java-exceptions/ for the gritty details.

The real question here is not "How slow are 'failures reported as exceptions' compared to 'code that never fails'?" as the accepted response might have you believe. Instead, the question should be "How slow are 'failures reported as exceptions' compared to failures reported other ways?" Generally, the two other ways of reporting failures are either with sentinel values or with result wrappers.

Sentinel values are an attempt to return one class in the case of success and another in the case of failure. You can think of it almost as returning an exception instead of throwing one. This requires a shared parent class with the success object and then doing an "instanceof" check and a couple casts to get the success or failure information.

It turns out that at the risk of type safety, Sentinel values are faster than exceptions, but only by a factor of roughly 2x. Now, that may seem like a lot, but that 2x only covers the cost of the implementation difference. In practice, the factor is much lower since our methods that might fail are much more interesting than a few arithmetic operators as in the sample code elsewhere in this page.

Result Wrappers, on the other hand, do not sacrifice type safety at all. They wrap the success and failure information in a single class. So instead of "instanceof" they provide an "isSuccess()" and getters for both the success and failure objects. However, result objects are roughly 2x **slower** than using exceptions. It turns out that creating a new wrapper object every time is much more expensive than throwing an exception sometimes.

On top of that, exceptions are the language supplied the way of indicating that a method might fail. There's no other way to tell from just the API which methods are expected to always (mostly) work and which are expected to report failure.

Exceptions are safer than sentinels, faster than result objects, and less surprising than either. I'm not suggesting that try/catch replace if/else, but exceptions are the right way to report failure, even in the business logic.

That said, I would like to point out that the two most frequent ways of substantially impacting performance I've run across are creating unnecessary objects and nested loops. If you have a choice between creating an exception or not creating an exception, don't create the exception. If you have a choice between creating an exception sometimes or creating another object all the time, then create the exception.

Comment: I decided to test the long term performance of the three implementations compared to a control implementation that checks for failure without reporting. The process has a failure rate of about 4%. An iteration of a test invokes the process 10000 times against one of the strategies. Each strategy is tested 1000 times and the last 900 times are used to generate the stats. Here are the average times in nanos:
Control 338
Exception 429
Result 348
Sentinel 345

Comment: Just for fun I disabled fillInStackTrace in the exception test. Here are the times now: Control 347 Exception 351 Result 364 Sentinel 355

Comment: Fuwjax, unless I am missing something (and I admit I've only read your SO post, not your blog post), it seems like your two comments above contradict your post. I presume lower numbers are better in your benchmark, right? In which case, generating exceptions with fillInStackTrace enabled (which is the default and usual behavior), results in slower performance than the other two techniques you describe. Am I missing something, or did you actually comment to disprove your post?

Comment: @Fuwjax - the way to avoid the "rock and hard place" choice you present here, is to **pre-allocate** an object that represents "success". Usually one can also pre-allocate objects for the common failure cases. Then only in the rare case of passing back additional detail, is a new object created. (This is the OO equivalent of integer "error codes", plus a separate call to get the details of the last error - a technique which has existed for decades.)

Comment: @Fuwjax So throwing an exception does not create an object by your account? Not sure I understand that reasoning. Whether you throw an exception or return a result object, you're creating objects. In that sense result objects are not slower than throwing an exception.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Flyweights are great when they make sense. The discussion around exceptions as failure response objects tends to revolve around wanting to use them as "objects" and not just as "failure response". So, how do you indicate non-trivial failure, what I infer you would call uncommon failure cases?

Comment: @FelixGV the numbers were meant as supporting details. Most micro-benchmarks around failure fail every time through the loop. I was curious about long-term performance in slight-to-moderate failure conditions, and thought it interesting enough to share. Presumably, the discussion around exception performance means you're tuning your code; in my opinion, disabling stack traces in performant code is less risky than Result wrappers or Sentinels, while remaining just as performant.

Comment: @Matthias Throwing an exception obviously creates an object. But thank you for pointing out that I wasn't being clear. The term Result Object above would be better understood as Result Wrapper. So, in addition to any failure response object you have to create a Result Wrapper. It is the additional wrapper instantiation that I was referring to. A good example in practice is the new Java 8 Optional object.

Answer (score 23):

I've extends the answers given by [@Mecki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299315/340290) and [@incarnate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980148/340290), without stacktrace filling for Java.

With Java 7+, we can use `Throwable(String message, Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression,boolean writableStackTrace)`. But for Java6, see [my answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25324497/340290)

```
// This one will regularly throw one
public void method4(int i) throws NoStackTraceThrowable {
    value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
    // i & 1 is equally fast to calculate as i & 0xFFFFFFF; it is both
    // an AND operation between two integers. The size of the number plays
    // no role. AND on 32 BIT always ANDs all 32 bits
    if ((i & 0x1) == 1) {
        throw new NoStackTraceThrowable();
    }
}

// This one will regularly throw one
public void method5(int i) throws NoStackTraceRuntimeException {
    value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
    // i & 1 is equally fast to calculate as i & 0xFFFFFFF; it is both
    // an AND operation between two integers. The size of the number plays
    // no role. AND on 32 BIT always ANDs all 32 bits
    if ((i & 0x1) == 1) {
        throw new NoStackTraceRuntimeException();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    long l;
    Test t = new Test();

    l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    t.reset();
    for (i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
        try {
            t.method4(i);
        } catch (NoStackTraceThrowable e) {
            // Do nothing here, as we will get here
        }
    }
    l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
    System.out.println( "method4 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.getValue() );


    l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    t.reset();
    for (i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
        try {
            t.method5(i);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // Do nothing here, as we will get here
        }
    }
    l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
    System.out.println( "method5 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.getValue() );
}
```

Output with Java 1.6.0_45, on Core i7, 8GB RAM:

```
method1 took 883 ms, result was 2
method2 took 882 ms, result was 2
method3 took 32270 ms, result was 2 // throws Exception
method4 took 8114 ms, result was 2 // throws NoStackTraceThrowable
method5 took 8086 ms, result was 2 // throws NoStackTraceRuntimeException
```

So, still methods which returns values are faster, compared to methods throwing exceptions. IMHO, we can't design a clear API just using return types for both success & error flows. Methods which throws exceptions without stacktrace are 4-5 times faster than normal Exceptions.

Edit: NoStackTraceThrowable.java *Thanks @Greg*

```
public class NoStackTraceThrowable extends Throwable { 
    public NoStackTraceThrowable() { 
        super("my special throwable", null, false, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, thanks. Here's the missing class declaration: `public class NoStackTraceThrowable extends Throwable {
    public NoStackTraceThrowable() {
      super("my special throwable", null, false, false);
    }
  }`

Comment: at beginging You wrote `With Java 7+, we can use` but later you wrote `Output with Java 1.6.0_45,` so this is Java 6 or 7 result?

Comment: @WBAR from Java 7, we just need to use the `Throwable` constructor which has `boolean writableStackTrace` arg. But that is not present in Java 6 and below. That is why I've given custom implementation for Java 6 and below. So the above code is for Java 6 & below. Please read 1st line of 2nd para carefully.

Comment: @manikanta "IMHO, we can't design a clear API just using return types for both success & error flows. " -- we can, if we use Optionals/Results/Maybe as many languages do.

Comment: @Hejazzman I agree. But `Optional` or similar came a bit late to Java. Before that also we used wrapper objects with success/error flags. But it seems to be a bit hacks and doesn't feel natural to me.

Comment: I'm afraid this benchmark is flawed, at least on recent Java versions.  Adding a loop in the main method to run the test multiple times will show all 5 methods taking about the same amount of time after the first loop.

Answer (score 9):

A while back I wrote a class to test the relative performance of converting strings to ints using two approaches: (1) call Integer.parseInt() and catch the exception, or (2) match the string with a regex and call parseInt() only if the match succeeds.  I used the regex in the most efficient way I could (i.e., creating the Pattern and Matcher objects before intering the loop), and I didn't print or save the stacktraces from the exceptions.

For a list of ten thousand strings, if they were all valid numbers the parseInt() approach was four times as fast as the regex approach.  But if only 80% of the strings were valid, the regex was twice as fast as parseInt().  And if 20% were valid, meaning the exception was thrown and caught 80% of the time, the regex was about twenty times as fast as parseInt().

I was surprised by the result, considering that the regex approach processes valid strings twice: once for the match and again for parseInt().  But throwing and catching exceptions more than made up for that.  This kind of situation isn't likely to occur very often in the real world, but if it does, you definitely should not use the exception-catching technique.  But if you're only validating user input or something like that, by all means use the parseInt() approach.

Comment: which JVM did you use? is it still that slow with sun-jdk 6?

Comment: I dug it up and ran it again under JDK 1.6u10 before submitting that answer, and those are the results I posted.

Comment: This is very, very useful! Thanks.

For my usual use cases I do need to parse user inputs (using something like `Integer.ParseInt()`) and I expect that **most of the times** the user input would be correct, so for my use case it seems like taking the occasional exception hit is the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

I think the first article refer to the act of traversing the call stack and creating a stack trace as being the expensive part, and while the second article doesn't say it, I think that is the most expensive part of object creation. John Rose has [an article where he describes different techniques for speeding up exceptions](http://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/longjumps_considered_inexpensive). (Preallocating and reusing an exception, exceptions without stack traces, etc)

But still - I think this should be considered only a necessary evil, a last resort. John's reason for doing this is to emulate features in other languages which aren't (yet) available in the JVM. You should NOT get into the habit of using exceptions for control flow. Especially not for performance reasons! As you yourself mention in #2, you risk masking serious bugs in your code this way, and it will be harder to maintain for new programmers.

Microbenchmarks in Java are surprisingly hard to get right (I've been told), especially when you get into JIT territory, so I really doubt that using exceptions is faster than "return" in real life. For instance, I suspect you have somewhere between 2 and 5 stack frames in your test? Now imagine your code will be invoked by a JSF component deployed by JBoss. Now you might have a stack trace which is several pages long.

Perhaps you could post your test code?

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 8):

Don't know if these topics relate, but I once wanted to implement one trick relying on current thread's stack trace: I wanted to discover the name of the method, which triggered the instantiation inside the instantiated class (yeap, the idea is crazy, I totally gave it up). So I discovered that calling `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` is **extremely** slow (due to native `dumpThreads` method which it uses internally).

So Java `Throwable`, correspondingly, has a native method `fillInStackTrace`. I think that the killer-`catch` block described earlier somehow triggers the execution of this method.

But let me tell you another story...

In Scala some functional features are compiled in JVM using `ControlThrowable`, which extends `Throwable` and overrides its `fillInStackTrace` in a following way:

```
override def fillInStackTrace(): Throwable = this
```

So I adapted the test above (cycles amount are decreased by ten, my machine is a bit slower :):

```
class ControlException extends ControlThrowable

class T {
  var value = 0

  def reset = {
    value = 0
  }

  def method1(i: Int) = {
    value = ((value + i) / i) << 1
    if ((i & 0xfffffff) == 1000000000) {
      println("You'll never see this!")
    }
  }

  def method2(i: Int) = {
    value = ((value + i) / i) << 1
    if ((i & 0xfffffff) == 1000000000) {
      throw new Exception()
    }
  }

  def method3(i: Int) = {
    value = ((value + i) / i) << 1
    if ((i & 0x1) == 1) {
      throw new Exception()
    }
  }

  def method4(i: Int) = {
    value = ((value + i) / i) << 1
    if ((i & 0x1) == 1) {
      throw new ControlException()
    }
  }
}

class Main {
  var l = System.currentTimeMillis
  val t = new T
  for (i <- 1 to 10000000)
    t.method1(i)
  l = System.currentTimeMillis - l
  println("method1 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.value)

  t.reset
  l = System.currentTimeMillis
  for (i <- 1 to 10000000) try {
    t.method2(i)
  } catch {
    case _ => println("You'll never see this")
  }
  l = System.currentTimeMillis - l
  println("method2 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.value)

  t.reset
  l = System.currentTimeMillis
  for (i <- 1 to 10000000) try {
    t.method4(i)
  } catch {
    case _ => // do nothing
  }
  l = System.currentTimeMillis - l
  println("method4 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.value)

  t.reset
  l = System.currentTimeMillis
  for (i <- 1 to 10000000) try {
    t.method3(i)
  } catch {
    case _ => // do nothing
  }
  l = System.currentTimeMillis - l
  println("method3 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.value)

}
```

So, the results are:

```
method1 took 146 ms, result was 2
method2 took 159 ms, result was 2
method4 took 1551 ms, result was 2
method3 took 42492 ms, result was 2
```

You see, the only difference between `method3` and `method4` is that they throw different kinds of exceptions. Yeap, `method4` is still slower than `method1` and `method2`, but the difference is far more acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

I've done some performance testing with JVM 1.5 and using exceptions was at least 2x slower. On average: Execution time on a trivially small method more than tripled (3x) with exceptions. A trivially small loop that had to catch the exception saw a 2x increase in self-time.

I've seen similar numbers in production code as well as micro benchmarks.

Exceptions should definately ***NOT*** be used for anything that's called frequently. Throwing a thousands of exceptions a second would cause a huge bottle neck.

For example, using "Integer.ParseInt(...)" to find all bad values in a very large text file--very bad idea. (I have seen this utility method *kill* performance on production code)

Using an exception to report a bad value on a user GUI form, probably not so bad from a performance standpoint.

Whether or not its a good design practice, I'd go with the rule: if the error is normal/expected, then use a return value. If it's abnormal, use an exception. For example: reading user inputs, bad values are normal--use an error code. Passing a value to an internal utility function, bad values should be filtered by calling code--use an exception.

Comment: Let me suggest some things that ARE good to do: If you need a number in a form, instead of using Integer.valueOf(String), you should consider using a regular expression matcher instead. You can precompile and reuse the pattern so making matchers are cheap. However on a GUI form, having an isValid/validate/checkField or what have you is probably clearer. Also, with Java 8 we have Optional monads, so consider using them. (the answer is 9 years old, but still! :p)

Answer (score 5):

Exception performance in Java and C# leaves much to be desired.

As programmers this forces us to live by the rule "exceptions should be caused infrequently", simply for practical performance reasons.

However, as computer scientists, we should rebel against this problematic state. The person authoring a function often has no idea how often it will be called, or whether success or failure is more likely. Only the caller has this information. Trying to avoid exceptions leads to unclear API idoms where in some cases we have only clean-but-slow exception versions, and in other cases we have fast-but-clunky return-value errors, and in still other cases we end up with both. The library implementor may have to write and maintain two versions of APIs, and the caller has to decide which of two versions to use in each situation.

This is kind of a mess. If exceptions had better performance, we could avoid these clunky idioms and use exceptions as they were meant to be used... as a structured error return facility.

I'd really like to see exception mechanisms implemented using techniques closer to return-values, so we could have performance closer to return values.. since this is what we revert to in performance sensitive code.

Here is a code-sample that compares exception performance to error-return-value performance.

public class TestIt {

```
int value;


public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void reset() {
    value = 0;
}

public boolean baseline_null(boolean shouldfail, int recurse_depth) {
    if (recurse_depth <= 0) {
        return shouldfail;
    } else {
        return baseline_null(shouldfail,recurse_depth-1);
    }
}

public boolean retval_error(boolean shouldfail, int recurse_depth) {
    if (recurse_depth <= 0) {
        if (shouldfail) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        boolean nested_error = retval_error(shouldfail,recurse_depth-1);
        if (nested_error) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public void exception_error(boolean shouldfail, int recurse_depth) throws Exception {
    if (recurse_depth <= 0) {
        if (shouldfail) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } else {
        exception_error(shouldfail,recurse_depth-1);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    long l;
    TestIt t = new TestIt();
    int failures;

    int ITERATION_COUNT = 100000000;


    // (0) baseline null workload
    for (int recurse_depth = 2; recurse_depth <= 10; recurse_depth+=3) {
        for (float exception_freq = 0.0f; exception_freq <= 1.0f; exception_freq += 0.25f) {            
            int EXCEPTION_MOD = (exception_freq == 0.0f) ? ITERATION_COUNT+1 : (int)(1.0f / exception_freq);            

            failures = 0;
            long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            t.reset();              
            for (i = 1; i < ITERATION_COUNT; i++) {
                boolean shoulderror = (i % EXCEPTION_MOD) == 0;
                t.baseline_null(shoulderror,recurse_depth);
            }
            long elapsed_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
            System.out.format("baseline: recurse_depth %s, exception_freqeuncy %s (%s), time elapsed %s ms\n",
                    recurse_depth, exception_freq, failures,elapsed_time);
        }
    }


    // (1) retval_error
    for (int recurse_depth = 2; recurse_depth <= 10; recurse_depth+=3) {
        for (float exception_freq = 0.0f; exception_freq <= 1.0f; exception_freq += 0.25f) {            
            int EXCEPTION_MOD = (exception_freq == 0.0f) ? ITERATION_COUNT+1 : (int)(1.0f / exception_freq);            

            failures = 0;
            long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            t.reset();              
            for (i = 1; i < ITERATION_COUNT; i++) {
                boolean shoulderror = (i % EXCEPTION_MOD) == 0;
                if (!t.retval_error(shoulderror,recurse_depth)) {
                    failures++;
                }
            }
            long elapsed_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
            System.out.format("retval_error: recurse_depth %s, exception_freqeuncy %s (%s), time elapsed %s ms\n",
                    recurse_depth, exception_freq, failures,elapsed_time);
        }
    }

    // (2) exception_error
    for (int recurse_depth = 2; recurse_depth <= 10; recurse_depth+=3) {
        for (float exception_freq = 0.0f; exception_freq <= 1.0f; exception_freq += 0.25f) {            
            int EXCEPTION_MOD = (exception_freq == 0.0f) ? ITERATION_COUNT+1 : (int)(1.0f / exception_freq);            

            failures = 0;
            long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            t.reset();              
            for (i = 1; i < ITERATION_COUNT; i++) {
                boolean shoulderror = (i % EXCEPTION_MOD) == 0;
                try {
                    t.exception_error(shoulderror,recurse_depth);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    failures++;
                }
            }
            long elapsed_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
            System.out.format("exception_error: recurse_depth %s, exception_freqeuncy %s (%s), time elapsed %s ms\n",
                    recurse_depth, exception_freq, failures,elapsed_time);              
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here are the results:

```
baseline: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.0 (0), time elapsed 683 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.25 (0), time elapsed 790 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.5 (0), time elapsed 768 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.75 (0), time elapsed 749 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 1.0 (0), time elapsed 731 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.0 (0), time elapsed 923 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.25 (0), time elapsed 971 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.5 (0), time elapsed 982 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.75 (0), time elapsed 947 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 1.0 (0), time elapsed 937 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.0 (0), time elapsed 1154 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.25 (0), time elapsed 1149 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.5 (0), time elapsed 1133 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.75 (0), time elapsed 1117 ms
baseline: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 1.0 (0), time elapsed 1116 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.0 (0), time elapsed 742 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.25 (24999999), time elapsed 743 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.5 (49999999), time elapsed 734 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.75 (99999999), time elapsed 723 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 1.0 (99999999), time elapsed 728 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.0 (0), time elapsed 920 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.25 (24999999), time elapsed 1121   ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.5 (49999999), time elapsed 1037 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.75 (99999999), time elapsed 1141   ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 1.0 (99999999), time elapsed 1130 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.0 (0), time elapsed 1218 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.25 (24999999), time elapsed 1334  ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.5 (49999999), time elapsed 1478 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.75 (99999999), time elapsed 1637 ms
retval_error: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 1.0 (99999999), time elapsed 1655 ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.0 (0), time elapsed 726 ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.25 (24999999), time elapsed 17487   ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.5 (49999999), time elapsed 33763   ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 0.75 (99999999), time elapsed 67367   ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 2, exception_freqeuncy 1.0 (99999999), time elapsed 66990 ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.0 (0), time elapsed 924 ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.25 (24999999), time elapsed 23775  ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.5 (49999999), time elapsed 46326 ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 0.75 (99999999), time elapsed 91707 ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 5, exception_freqeuncy 1.0 (99999999), time elapsed 91580 ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.0 (0), time elapsed 1144 ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.25 (24999999), time elapsed 30440 ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.5 (49999999), time elapsed 59116   ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 0.75 (99999999), time elapsed 116678 ms
exception_error: recurse_depth 8, exception_freqeuncy 1.0 (99999999), time elapsed 116477 ms
```

Checking and propagating return-values does add some cost vs the baseline-null call, and that cost is proportional to call-depth. At a call-chain depth of 8, the error-return-value checking version was about 27% slower than the basline version which did not check return values.

Exception performance, in comparison, is not a function of call-depth, but of exception frequency. However, the degredation as exception frequency increases is much more dramatic. At only a 25% error frequency, the code ran 24-TIMES slower. At an error frequency of 100%, the exception version is almost 100-TIMES slower.

This suggests to me that perhaps are making the wrong tradeoffs in our exception implementations. Exceptions could be faster, either by avoiding costly stalk-walks, or by outright turning them into compiler supported return-value checking. Until they do, we're stuck avoiding them when we want our code to run fast.

Answer (score 3):

HotSpot is quite capable of removing exception code for system generated exceptions, so long as it is all inlined. However, explicitly created exception and those otherwise not removed spend a lot of time creating the stack trace. Override `fillInStackTrace` to see how this can affect performance.

Answer (score 3):

Great post about exception performance is:

https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/

Instantiating vs reusing existing, with stack trace and without, etc:

```
Benchmark                            Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error  Units

dynamicException                     avgt        25     1901.196       14.572  ns/op
dynamicException_NoStack             avgt        25       67.029        0.212  ns/op
dynamicException_NoStack_UsedData    avgt        25       68.952        0.441  ns/op
dynamicException_NoStack_UsedStack   avgt        25      137.329        1.039  ns/op
dynamicException_UsedData            avgt        25     1900.770        9.359  ns/op
dynamicException_UsedStack           avgt        25    20033.658      118.600  ns/op

plain                                avgt        25        1.259        0.002  ns/op
staticException                      avgt        25        1.510        0.001  ns/op
staticException_NoStack              avgt        25        1.514        0.003  ns/op
staticException_NoStack_UsedData     avgt        25        4.185        0.015  ns/op
staticException_NoStack_UsedStack    avgt        25       19.110        0.051  ns/op
staticException_UsedData             avgt        25        4.159        0.007  ns/op
staticException_UsedStack            avgt        25       25.144        0.186  ns/op
```

Depending on depth of stack trace:

```
Benchmark        Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error  Units

exception_0000   avgt        25     1959.068       30.783  ns/op
exception_0001   avgt        25     1945.958       12.104  ns/op
exception_0002   avgt        25     2063.575       47.708  ns/op
exception_0004   avgt        25     2211.882       29.417  ns/op
exception_0008   avgt        25     2472.729       57.336  ns/op
exception_0016   avgt        25     2950.847       29.863  ns/op
exception_0032   avgt        25     4416.548       50.340  ns/op
exception_0064   avgt        25     6845.140       40.114  ns/op
exception_0128   avgt        25    11774.758       54.299  ns/op
exception_0256   avgt        25    21617.526      101.379  ns/op
exception_0512   avgt        25    42780.434      144.594  ns/op
exception_1024   avgt        25    82839.358      291.434  ns/op
```

For other details (including x64 assembler from JIT) read original blog post.

That means Hibernate/Spring/etc-EE-shit are slow because of exceptions (xD).

By rewriting app control flow with avoiding exceptions (returning error as a `return`) improve performance of your application 10x-100x, depending on how often you throws them  ))

Comment: The post is great, your conclusion however about Hibernate/Spring/EE being slow because of exceptions is however not based on anything your provided here.  If your Hibernate/Spring app is maxing out its CPU's, then it *might* be this.  Much more likely however it is something else. Other reasons for poor performance is a complete lack of understanding of what Hibernate does under the hood and that using an ORM does not magically mean you get good performance without carefully checking if the SQL statements it is executing (and how many) are not horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Even if throwing an exception isn't slow, it's still a bad idea to throw exceptions for normal program flow. Used this way it is analogous to a GOTO...

I guess that doesn't really answer the question though. I'd imagine that the 'conventional' wisdom of throwing exceptions being slow was true in earlier java versions (< 1.4). Creating an exception requires that the VM create the entire stack trace. A lot has changed since then in the VM to speed things up and this is likely one area that has been improved.

Comment: It would be good to define "normal program flow". Much has been written about using checked exceptions as a business process failure and an unchecked exception for non-recoverable failures, so in a sense, a failure in business logic could still be thought of as normal flow.

Comment: @Spencer K: An exception, as the name implies, means that an exceptional situation was discovered (a file went away, a network suddenly closed, ...). This implies that the situation was UNEXPECTED. If it is EXPECTED that the situation will occur, I'd not use an exception for it.

Comment: @Mecki: right. I recently had a discussion with someone about this... They were writing a Validation framework and were throwing an exception in case of validation failure. I think this is a bad idea as this would be quite common. I'd rather see the method return a ValidationResult.

Comment: @Mecki: Well, `Throwable` is the superclass of `Exception`, and the name *Throwable* doesn't imply something unusual has happened.

Comment: In terms of control flow, an exception is analogous to a `break` or `return`, not a `goto`.

Comment: There are tons of programming paradigms. There can't be a single “normal flow”, whatever you mean by that. Basically, the exception mechanism is just a way to quickly leave the current frame and unwind the stack until a certain point. The word “exception” implies nothing about its “unexpected” nature. A quick example: it is very natural to “throw” 404s from web applications when certain circumstances occur along the routing way. Why wouldn't that logic be implemented with exceptions? What's the anti-pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Just compare let's say Integer.parseInt to the following method, which just returns a default value in the case of unparseable data instead of throwing an Exception:

```
  public static int parseUnsignedInt(String s, int defaultValue) {
    final int strLength = s.length();
    if (strLength == 0)
      return defaultValue;
    int value = 0;
    for (int i=strLength-1; i>=0; i--) {
      int c = s.charAt(i);
      if (c > 47 && c < 58) {
        c -= 48;
        for (int j=strLength-i; j!=1; j--)
          c *= 10;
        value += c;
      } else {
        return defaultValue;
      }
    }
    return value < 0 ? /* übergebener wert > Integer.MAX_VALUE? */ defaultValue : value;
  }
```

As long as you apply both methods to "valid" data, they both will work at approximately the same rate (even although Integer.parseInt manages to handle more complex data). But as soon as you try to parse invalid data (e.g. to parse "abc" 1.000.000 times), the difference in performance should be essential.

Answer (score 1):

Using the attached code, on JDK 15, I get completely different results for the @Mecki test case. This basically runs the code in 5 loops, with the first loop a bit shorter to give the VM some time to warm up.

The results:

```
Loop 1 10000 cycles
method1 took 1 ms, result was 2
method2 took 0 ms, result was 2
method3 took 22 ms, result was 2
method4 took 22 ms, result was 2
method5 took 24 ms, result was 2
Loop 2 10000000 cycles
method1 took 39 ms, result was 2
method2 took 39 ms, result was 2
method3 took 1558 ms, result was 2
method4 took 1640 ms, result was 2
method5 took 1717 ms, result was 2
Loop 3 10000000 cycles
method1 took 49 ms, result was 2
method2 took 48 ms, result was 2
method3 took 126 ms, result was 2
method4 took 88 ms, result was 2
method5 took 87 ms, result was 2
Loop 4 10000000 cycles
method1 took 34 ms, result was 2
method2 took 34 ms, result was 2
method3 took 33 ms, result was 2
method4 took 98 ms, result was 2
method5 took 58 ms, result was 2
Loop 5 10000000 cycles
method1 took 34 ms, result was 2
method2 took 33 ms, result was 2
method3 took 33 ms, result was 2
method4 took 48 ms, result was 2
method5 took 49 ms, result was 2
```

```
package hs.jfx.eventstream.api;

public class Snippet {
  int value;


  public int getValue() {
      return value;
  }

  public void reset() {
      value = 0;
  }

  // Calculates without exception
  public void method1(int i) {
      value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
      // Will never be true
      if ((i & 0xFFFFFFF) == 1000000000) {
          System.out.println("You'll never see this!");
      }
  }

  // Could in theory throw one, but never will
  public void method2(int i) throws Exception {
      value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
      // Will never be true
      if ((i & 0xFFFFFFF) == 1000000000) {
          throw new Exception();
      }
  }

  private static final NoStackTraceRuntimeException E = new NoStackTraceRuntimeException();

  // This one will regularly throw one
  public void method3(int i) throws NoStackTraceRuntimeException {
      value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
      // i & 1 is equally fast to calculate as i & 0xFFFFFFF; it is both
      // an AND operation between two integers. The size of the number plays
      // no role. AND on 32 BIT always ANDs all 32 bits
      if ((i & 0x1) == 1) {
          throw E;
      }
  }

  // This one will regularly throw one
  public void method4(int i) throws NoStackTraceThrowable {
      value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
      // i & 1 is equally fast to calculate as i & 0xFFFFFFF; it is both
      // an AND operation between two integers. The size of the number plays
      // no role. AND on 32 BIT always ANDs all 32 bits
      if ((i & 0x1) == 1) {
          throw new NoStackTraceThrowable();
      }
  }

  // This one will regularly throw one
  public void method5(int i) throws NoStackTraceRuntimeException {
      value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
      // i & 1 is equally fast to calculate as i & 0xFFFFFFF; it is both
      // an AND operation between two integers. The size of the number plays
      // no role. AND on 32 BIT always ANDs all 32 bits
      if ((i & 0x1) == 1) {
          throw new NoStackTraceRuntimeException();
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
      int cycles = 10000000;
      if(k == 0) {
        cycles = 10000;
        try {
          Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Loop " + (k + 1) + " " + cycles + " cycles");
      int i;
      long l;
      Snippet t = new Snippet();

      l = System.currentTimeMillis();
      t.reset();
      for (i = 1; i < cycles; i++) {
          t.method1(i);
      }
      l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
      System.out.println(
          "method1 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.getValue()
      );

      l = System.currentTimeMillis();
      t.reset();
      for (i = 1; i < cycles; i++) {
          try {
              t.method2(i);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("You'll never see this!");
          }
      }
      l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
      System.out.println(
          "method2 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.getValue()
      );

      l = System.currentTimeMillis();
      t.reset();
      for (i = 1; i < cycles; i++) {
          try {
              t.method3(i);
          } catch (NoStackTraceRuntimeException e) {
            // always comes here
          }
      }
      l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
      System.out.println(
          "method3 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.getValue()
      );


      l = System.currentTimeMillis();
      t.reset();
      for (i = 1; i < cycles; i++) {
          try {
              t.method4(i);
          } catch (NoStackTraceThrowable e) {
            // always comes here
          }
      }
      l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
      System.out.println( "method4 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.getValue() );


      l = System.currentTimeMillis();
      t.reset();
      for (i = 1; i < cycles; i++) {
          try {
              t.method5(i);
          } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // always comes here
          }
      }
      l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
      System.out.println( "method5 took " + l + " ms, result was " + t.getValue() );
    }
  }

  public static class NoStackTraceRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {
    public NoStackTraceRuntimeException() {
        super("my special throwable", null, false, false);
    }
  }

  public static class NoStackTraceThrowable extends Throwable {
    public NoStackTraceThrowable() {
        super("my special throwable", null, false, false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But how is that relevant? My benchmark was not for proving that exceptions are slow, it was just for testing if they are. I only shared my results as a sample output, not to prove any point. They might now be implemented in a different way, well, as I explained, there are many ways you can implement them. How does that falsify anything I've written in my answer? Which part of the first sentence of my answer was unclear when I said it depends? It also depends on the system, the JVM code is not identical for all systems and all I said is "don't rely that they are fast". So I miss your point here

Comment: I came here looking for an answer to a question. When I find that something in a current answer is no longer accurate on recent hardware/versions, I tend to leave a comment so others might get better informed.

Answer (score 0):

I changed @Mecki 's answer above to have method1 return a boolean and a check in the calling method, as you cannot just replace an Exception with nothing. After two runs, method1 was still either the fastest or as fast as method2.

Here is snapshot of the code:

```
// Calculates without exception
public boolean method1(int i) {
    value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
    // Will never be true
    return ((i & 0xFFFFFFF) == 1000000000);

}
....
   for (i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
            if (t.method1(i)) {
                System.out.println("Will never be true!");
            }
    }
```

and results:

Run 1

```
method1 took 841 ms, result was 2
method2 took 841 ms, result was 2
method3 took 85058 ms, result was 2
```

Run 2

```
method1 took 821 ms, result was 2
method2 took 838 ms, result was 2
method3 took 85929 ms, result was 2
```

Answer (score -3):

My opinion about Exception speed versus checking data programmatically.

Many classes had String to value converter (scanner / parser), respected and well-known libraries too ;)

usually has form

```
class Example {
public static Example Parse(String input) throws AnyRuntimeParsigException
...
}
```

exception name is only example, usually is unchecked (runtime), so throws declaration is only my picture

sometimes exist second form:

```
public static Example Parse(String input, Example defaultValue)
```

never throwing

When the second ins't available (or programmer read too less docs and use only first), write such code with regular expression. Regular expression are cool, politically correct etc:

```
Xxxxx.regex(".....pattern", src);
if(ImTotallySure)
{
  Example v = Example.Parse(src);
}
```

with this code programmers hasn't cost of exceptions. BUT HAS comparable very HIGH cost of regular expressions ALWAYS versus small cost of exception sometimes.

I use almost always in such context

```
try { parse } catch(ParsingException ) // concrete exception from javadoc
{
}
```

without analysing stacktrace etc, I believe after lectures of Yours quite speed.

Do not be afraid Exceptions

Answer (score -6):

Why should exceptions be any slower than normal returns?

As long as you don't print the stacktrace to the terminal, save it into a file or something similar, the catch-block doesn't do any more work than other code-blocks. So, I can't imagine why "throw new my_cool_error()" should be that slow.

Good question and I'm looking forward to further information on this topic!

Comment: The exception has to capture the information about the stack trace, even if it doesn't actually get used.