# Extending Throwable in Java

Tags: java, exception, throwable

Java lets you create an entirely new subtype of `Throwable`, e.g:

```
public class FlyingPig extends Throwable { ... }
```

Now, *very rarely*, I may do something like this:

```
throw new FlyingPig("Oink!");
```

and of course elsewhere:

```
try { ... } catch (FlyingPig porky) { ... }
```

My questions are:

- Is this a bad idea? And if so, why?

  - What could've been done to prevent this subtyping if it is a bad idea?
  - Since it's not preventable (as far as I know), what catastrophies could result?
- If this isn't such a bad idea, why not?

  - How can you make something useful out of the fact that you can `extends Throwable`?

---

#### Proposed scenario #1

A scenario where I was *really* tempted to do something like this has the following properties:

- The "event" is something that *will* happen eventually. It is **expected**. It most definitely is not an `Error`, and there's nothing `Exception`-al about when it occurs.

  - Because it is **expected**, there will be a `catch` waiting for it. It will not "slip" past anything. It will not "escape" from any attempt to `catch` general `Exception` and/or `Error`.
- The "event" happens *extremely rarely*.
- When it happens, usually there's a deep stack trace.

So perhaps it's clear now what I'm trying to say: `FlyingPig` is the *result* of an exhaustive recursive search.

The object to be searched exists: it's only a matter of finding it in the big sea that is the search space. The search process will be a long one, so the relatively expensive cost of exception handling is negligible. In fact, the traditional control flow construct alternative of using a `boolean isFound` flag may be more expensive, because it has to be checked continuously throughout the search process, most likely at every level of the recursion. This check will fail 99.99% of the time, but it's absolutely necessary to propagate the termination condition. In a way, while *effective*, the check is *inefficient*!

By simply `throw`-ing a `FlyingPig` when the sought object is found, you don't have to clutter the code with the management of the `boolean isFound` flag. Not only is the code cleaner in that regard, but it may run faster due to this omission.

So to summarize, the choice is between these two:

- Traditional control-flow approach

  - Use a `boolean isFound`, checked continuously
  - 99.99% of the time, the check is a "waste", because it'd still be `false`
  - When it eventually becomes `true`, you stop recursing and you have to make sure that you can properly unwind to the initial call.
- `FlyingPig` approach

  - Don't bother with any `boolean isFound`.
  - If found, just `throw new FlyingPig()`; it's **expected**, so there will be a `catch` for it.
  - No management of `boolean` flag, no wasted check if you need to keep going, no bookkeeping to manually unwind the recursion, etc.

Questions:

- Is this technique of (ab)using exception valid? (Is there a name for it?)
- If valid, should `FlyingPig extends Throwable`, or is `Exception` just fine? (even though there's nothing exceptional about its circumstances?)

Comment: Funny idea, I am just thinking if this can be used to let JVM synchronize threads. Is catching throwables asynchronous?

Comment: I have once used a `class Finished extends Exception` for exactly the same reason: Performance of breaking out of a long recursive search. But I never justified that reason by actually measuring the performance.

Comment: @Christian: Finally! Someone who had the same idea as I did! I probably should take it a step further and benchmark. Probably will someday.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd say that it is a really bad idea.  A lot of code is implemented on the assumption that if you catch `Error` and `Exception` you have caught all possible exceptions.  And most tutorials and textbooks will tell you the same thing.  By creating a direct subclass of `Throwable` you are potentially creating all sorts of maintenance and interoperability problems.

I can think of no good reason to extend `Throwable`.  Extend `Exception` or `RuntimeException` instead.

**EDIT**  - In response to the OP's proposed scenario #1.

Exceptions are a very expensive way of dealing with "normal" flow control.  In some cases, we are talking *thousands* of extra instructions executed to create, throw and catch an exception.  If you are going to ignore accepted wisdom and use exceptions for non-exceptional flow control, use an `Exception` subtype.  Trying to pretend something is an "event" not an "exception" by declaring is as a subtype of `Throwable` is not going to achieve anything.

However, it is a mistake to conflate an exception with an error, mistake, wrong, whatever.  And there is *nothing wrong* with representing an "exceptional event that is not an error, mistake, wrong, or whatever" using a subclass of `Exception`.  The key is that the event should be *exceptional*; i.e. out of the ordinary, happening very infrequently, ...

In summary, a `FlyingPig` may not be an error, but that is no reason not to declare it as a subtype of `Exception`.

Comment: +1, but I'd say it's almost always a bad idea, unless you know that it's exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @Stephen Denne - in 10+ years of Java coding, I've yet to come across a situation where extending Throwable would have been a good idea.  Granted, it is not impossible that such a situation might exist ...

Comment: Regarding cost: I probably should just benchmark this, but I think tens of millions of `boolean` test may be more expensive in the long run than one exception handling. Like I've emphasized, the search is a lengthy one: it may take minutes, even hours. See also my comment on Pascal's answer.

Comment: @polygenelubricants - the use-case sounds reasonable for exceptions, especially if it *also* significantly simplifies the code.

Comment: When would you extend a RuntimeException class?

Comment: @DougHauf - When I *want* the exception to be unchecked.

Answer (score 8):

> Is this technique of (ab)using exception valid? (Is there a name for it?)

In my opinion, it's not a good idea:

- It violates the [principle of least astonishment](https://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment), it makes the code harder to read, especially if there is nothing exception-al about it.
- Throwing exception is a very expensive operation in Java (might not be a problem here though).

Exception should just [not be used for flow control](https://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl). If I had to name this technique, I would call it a code smell or an anti pattern.

See also:

- [Throwing exceptions to control flow - code smell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465953/throwing-exceptions-to-control-flow-code-smell)

> If valid, should `FlyingPig` extends `Throwable`, or is `Exception` just fine? (even though there's nothing exceptional about its circumstances?)

There might be situations where you want to **catch** `Throwable` to not only catch `Exception` **but also** `Error` but it's rare, people usually don't catch `Throwable`. But I fail at finding a situation where you'd like to **throw** a subclass of `Throwable`.

And I also think that extending `Throwable` does not make things look less *"exception-al"*, they make it look worse - which totally defeats the intention.

So to conclude, if you really want to throw something, throw a subclass of `Exception`.

See also:

- [When should Throwable be used instead of new Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498217/when-should-throwable-be-used-instead-of-new-exception)

Comment: +1, but you didn't address the fact that handling an exception that happens very rarely may be cheaper than wasting time on traditional control flow that is ineffective 99.99% of the time. Also, when you `throw` a `FlyingPig`, you `catch` a `FlyingPig`. I never proposed that one should `catch (Throwable t)` (which I agree is a bad idea).

Comment: @polygenelubricants To clarify, I agree with your first remark, the performance cost is not a good argument here. But still, throwing an exception (with a little e) for something that is not exception-al is astonishing. That's not what most readers of the code would expect in my opinion. Regarding the second point, my intention was not to say that you proposed to `catch (Throwable t)` - you didn't - but that this seems to be the only reasonable use of `Throwable` for me (catching it, not throwing it). I've updated my answer, hope things are clearer.

Comment: Could you explain this - "Throwing exception is a very expensive operation in Java."? Or at least provide references. As far as I know, filling in the stack trace is expensive, but every other part of exception processing isn't that bad.

Comment: @Jack What I meant is that the whole `throw new Exception()` is expensive. Regarding references, check [Java Performance Tuning](http://books.google.com/books?id=iPHtCfZQyqQC&lpg=PT190&ots=tbnuHT3jnN&pg=PT190#v=onepage&q&f=false) for example (but any search about "Java+performance+cost+exception" will find many of them).

Comment: `private static final FlyingPig SHARED_EXCEPTION = (FlyingPig) new Flying().fillInStackTrace();` followed by `throw SHARED_EXCEPTION;` would avoid filling the stack trace, no?  (OK, if you want the exception to have state you'll need an "exception pool" and manage multi-threading, but if you're throwing flying pigs then you're probably crazy enough for anything...)  @Pascal thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a blog post from John Rose, a HotSpot architect:

http://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/longjumps_considered_inexpensive

It is about "abusing" exceptions for flow control. Slightly different use case, but..
In short, it works really well - if you preallocate/clone your exceptions to prevent stack traces being created.

I think that this technique is justifiable if "hidden" from clients. 
IE, your FlyingPig should never be able to leave your library (all public methods should transitively guarantee not to throw it). One way to guarantee this would be to make it a checked Exception.

I think the only justification for extending Throwable is because you want to allow people to pass in callbacks that have catch(Exception e) clauses , and you wish your result to be ignored by them. I can just about buy that...

Comment: *"I can just about buy that... "*.  I don't because 1) they shouldn't catch Exception, 2) they could (alternatively) catch Throwable, and 3) it is simpler to say in the javadocs "don't catch Exception in your callback".

Answer (score 4):

The `org.junit.Test` annotation includes the `None` class which extends `Throwable` and is used as the default value for the `expected` annotation parameter.

Comment: Too clever by half, IMO.  `None` could equally have been declared as a regular subclass of `Exception`.  And certainly, this is not an example to follow in other situations.

Answer (score 4):

If you can justify what sets a FlyingPig apart from both Error and Exception, such that it is not suitable as a subclass of either, then there's nothing fundamentally wrong with creating it.

The biggest problem I can think of is in the pragmatic world, sometimes there are justifiable reasons to catch java.lang.Exception.  Your new type of throwable is going to fly right past try-catch blocks that had every reasonable expectation of suppressing (or logging, wrapping, whatever) every possible non-fatal problem.

On the flipside if you're doing maintenance on an old system that is **un**justifiably suppressing java.lang.Exception, you could cheat around it.  (Assuming the sincere appeal for time to actually fix it properly is denied).

Answer (score 2):

> As this question has evolved, I see
>   that I misunderstood the point of the
>   original question, so some of the
>   other answers are probably more
>   relevant.  I will leave this answer up
>   here, since it may still be helpful to
>   others who have a similar question,
>   and find this page while searching for
>   an answer to their question.

There is nothing wrong with extending Throwable to be able to throw (and handle) custom exceptions.  However, you should keep the following points in mind:

- Using the most specific exception possible is a great idea.  It will allow the caller to handle different types of exceptions differently.  The class hierarchy of the exception is important to keep in mind, so your custom exception should extend another type of Throwable that is as close to your exception as possible.
- Extending Throwable might be too high-level.  Try extending Exception or RuntimeException instead (or a lower-level exception that is closer to the reason you are throwing an exception).  Keep in mind the difference between a RuntimeException and an Exception.
- A call to a method that throws an Exception (or a subclass of Exception) will need to be wrapped in a try/catch block that is capable of dealing with the exception.  This is good for cases when you expect things to go wrong, due to circumstances that may be out of your control (eg, the network being down).
- A call to a method that throws a RuntimeException (or a subclass of it) does not need to be wrapped in a try/catch block that can handle the exception.  (It certainly could be, but it doesn't need to be.)  THis is more for exceptions that really shouldn't be expected.

So, suppose you have the following exception classes in your code base:

```
public class Pig extends Throwable { ... }
public class FlyingPig extends Pig { ... }
public class Swine extends Pig { ... }
public class CustomRuntimeException extends RuntimeException { ... }
```

And some methods

```
public void foo() throws Pig { ... }
public void bar() throws FlyingPig, Swine { ... }
// suppose this next method could throw a CustomRuntimeException, but it
// doesn't need to be declared, since CustomRuntimeException is a subclass
// of RuntimeException
public void baz() { ... }
```

Now, you could have some code that calls these methods like this:

```
try {
    foo();
} catch (Pig e) {
    ...
}

try {
    bar();
} catch (Pig e) {
    ...
}

baz();
```

Note that when we call `bar()`, we can just catch `Pig`, since both `FlyingPig` and `Swine` extend `Pig`.  This is useful if you want to do the same thing to handle either exception.  You could, however, handle them differently:

```
try {
    bar();
} catch (FlyingPig e) {
    ...
} catch (Swine e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This does not address the question, which is whether directly inheriting the rarely-catched Throwable class is safe.

Answer (score 2):

The [Play! framework](http://www.playframework.org/) uses something like this for request handling. The request processing goes through many layers (routing, middleware, controllers, template rendering) and at the final layer the rendered HTML is [wrapped in a throwable](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~play-developers/play/1.0/annotate/head%3A/framework/src/play/mvc/results/Result.java) and thrown, which the top most layer catches, unwraps and sends to the client. So none of the methods in the many layers involved need to explicitly return a response object, nor do they need to have a response object passed as argument to be propagated and modified.

I am bit sketchy on details. You can look through the code of Play! framework for details.

Comment: Is there a name for this idiom that you know of?

Comment: I don't know the name of this idiom. I just came across it while reading the source of the framework.

Comment: It feels like a wormhole - disappear at one point of stack and appear at a different point, without going through the part in between. Not sure if that is a good thing.

Comment: The 2nd link in your answer is borked.  (I'm not sure if it is permanently borked ...)