# Generic Way of Creating workbook Apache POI

Tags: java, coding-style, apache-poi

I have a method that reads an excel sheet using Apache POI library. To make that method generic, I need to to write some code in a catch block. Here's the method:

```
private List<String[]> readFile(String filePath) throws IOException{
        List<String[]> sheetValues = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        //Two types of fileInputStreams for both the types of workbook i am about to use
        //
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        FileInputStream fileInputStream2 = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        LineItemFileReader fileReader = new LineItemFileReaderImpl();
        //If the file is in xls format i should use HSSFWorkbook
        //If the file is in xlsx format i should use XSSFWorkbook
        try {
        //If the file is in xlsx format then the below line will throw the
        //Exception and catch block code will be executed
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            sheetValues = fileReader.ParseSheet(workbook.getSheetAt(1),evaluator);
        } catch (OfficeXmlFileException exception){
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream2);
            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            sheetValues = fileReader.ParseSheet(workbook.getSheetAt(1),evaluator);
        } finally{
            fileInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream2.close();
        }
        return sheetValues;
    }
```

So what's happening here is that I dont know what type of file I am being supplied. I am deciding that on the basis of the try/catch block given above. So is there any generic way of deciding which workbook to use? Since the above code has flow control logic written in a catch block, it's a bad practice.

Comment: It entirely depends on what that error condition is, and what the method's job is.

Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465953/throwing-exceptions-to-control-flow-code-smell

Comment: Having try-catch blocks is not necessarily bad! I don't geht the point. Post some code that shows your problem!

Comment: @isnot2bad Posted the code! see the edit!

Comment: Can't you simply check the file extension?

Comment: Isn't there a possibility that the user might have named it as xls file but the file format is of xlsx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WorkbookFactory.create(...)` for opening the `Workbook`. It will create the appropriate subclass internally:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(filePath));
// ...
workbook.close();
```