# Java Null Reference Best Practice

Tags: java, coding-style

In java, Which of the following is the more "accepted" way of dealing with possibly null references? note that a null reference does not always indicate an error...

```
if (reference == null) {
    //create new reference or whatever
}
else {
    //do stuff here
}
```

or

```
try {
    //do stuff here
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    //create new reference or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Catching exceptions is relatively expensive. It's usually better to detect the condition rather than react to it.

Comment: Thanks. I figured "why check for null when the JVM does it for me, i could just use that check", but if catching it is so expensive, i'll just do the check myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 14):

The answers already given are excellent (don't use exceptions for control flow; exceptions are expensive to throw and handle).  There's one other important reason specifically not to catch `NullPointerException`.

Consider a code block that does the following:

```
try {
    reference.someMethod();
    // Some other code
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // 'reference' was null, right? Not so fast...
}
```

This might seem like a safe way to handle nullity of `reference` ...but what if reference was non-null and `someMethod()` raised NPE?  Or what if there was a NPE raised elsewhere in the `try` block?  Catching NPE is a surefire way to prevent bugs from being found and fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Of course this one

```
if (reference == null) {
    //create new reference or whatever
}
else {
    //do stuff here
}
```

we shouldn't rely on exception for decision making, that aren't given for that purpose at all, also they are expensive.

---

Well If you aren't making decision and just verifying for initialized variable then

```
if (reference == null) {
    //create new reference or whatever
}
//use this variable now safely
```

---

I have seen some auto code generator wraps up this thing in accessors/getter method.

Answer (score 2):

I think in general an exception should be reserved for exceptional circumstances - if a null reference is sometimes expected,  you should check for it and handle it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

From the answers its clear that catching an exception is not good. :)
Exceptions are definitely not free of cost. [This might help you to understand it in depth.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions) .

I would also like to mention an another practice while comparing your object with a *known* value.
This is the traditional way to do the job: (check whether the object is null or not and then compare)

```
Object obj = ??? //We dont know whether its null or not.
if(obj!=null && obj.equals(Constants.SOME_CONSTANT)){
    //your logic
}
```

but in this way, you dont have to bother about your object:

```
Object obj = ???
if(Constants.SOME_CONSTANT.equals(obj)){  //this will never throw 
                                          //nullpointer as constant can not be null.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one, throwing exceptions is a costly operation.

Answer (score 1):

The first form:

```
if (reference == null)
{    
    //create new reference or whatever
}
else 
{    
    //do stuff here
}
```

You should not use exceptions for control flow.

Exceptions are for handling exceptional circumstances that would not normally occur during normal operating conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use exception catching where you do not expect there to be an error. If something *can* be null, then you should check for that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the try catch approach will start making sense in this situation when we can start doing

```
try {
  //do stuff here
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
  //create new reference or whatever
  retry;
}
```

Comment: Not really, you are still throwing an unnecessary exception.
Better use `if (reference == null) {
    // create new reference 
   retry;
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is related to your style of development, if you are developing code using "safe" style you have to use

```
    if(null == myInstance){
// some code    
    }else{
// some code
    }
```

but if you do not use this style at least you should catch exception, but in this case it NullPointerException and I think preferably to check input parameters to null and not wait to throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for Best Practices, I want to point out that [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com) suggests to introduce a subclass for null references as best practice.

```
public class NullCustomer extends Customer {}
```

Thus, you avoiding the hassle of dealing with NullPointerException's, which are unchecked. Methods which might return a Customer value of null, would then instead return a NullCustomer instead of null.

Your check would look like:

```
final Customer c = findCustomerById( id );
if ( c instanceof NullCustomer ) {
    // customer not found, do something ...
} else {
    // normal customer treatment
    printCustomer( c );
}
```

In my opinion, it is permissible in some cases to catch a NullPointerException to avoid complex checks for null references and enhance code readability, e.g.

```
private void printCustomer( final Customer c ) {
try {
    System.out.println( "Customer " + c.getSurname() + " " + c.getName() + "living in " +     c.getAddress().getCity() + ", " + c.getAddress().getStreet() );
} catch ( NullPointerException ex ) {
    System.err.println( "Unable to print out customer information.", ex );
}
```

An argument against it is that by checking for individual members being null, you can write a more detailed error message, but that is often not necessary.