# Find out a method's name in Groovy

Tags: reflection, groovy, introspection

Is there a way in Groovy to find out the name of the called method?

```
def myMethod() {
    println "This method is called method " + methodName
}
```

This, in combination with duck typing would allow for quite concise (and probably hard to read) code.

Comment: Take a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540678/groovy-get-enclosing-functions-name

Comment: Thanks, I have not found this one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as with Java there's no native way of doing this.

You could write an AST transform so that you could annotate the method and this could set a local variable inside the method.

Or you can do it the good old Java way of generating a stackTrace, and finding the correct StackTraceElement with something like:

```
import static org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils.sanitize

def myMethod() {
  def name = sanitize( new Exception().fillInStackTrace() ).stackTrace.find {
    !( it.className ==~ /^java_.*|^org.codehaus.*/ )
  }?.methodName

  println "In method $name"
}

myMethod()
```

Answer (score 9):

Groovy supports the ability to intercept all methods through the `invokeMethod` mechanism of GroovyObject.

You can override `invokeMethod` which will essentially intercept all method calls (to intercept calls to existing methods, the class additionally has to implement the `GroovyInterceptable` interface).

```
class MyClass implements GroovyInterceptable {
    def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
        System.out.println("This method is called method $name")
        def metaMethod = metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
        metaMethod.invoke(this, args)
    }

    def myMethod() {
        "Hi!"
    }
}

def instance = new MyClass()
instance.myMethod()
```

Also, you can add this functionality to an existing class:

```
Integer.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
    println("This method is called method $name")
    def metaMethod = delegate.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
    metaMethod.invoke(delegate, args)
}

1.toString()
```