# How do I intercept calls in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have this class structure:

```
interface bug
{
    def method()    
}

public class A implements bug{
    def method()
    {
        println "Works"
    }
}

A varaiable = new A()

bug.metaClass.invokeMethod {
    name,args ->
        println "Came here"
}

varaiable.method()
```

when I do this, I get `Works`. Why not `Came here`?

Where I'm doing the mistake?

#### EDIT:

Even if I do:

```
A.metaClass.invokeMethod {
    name,args ->
        println "Came here"
}
```

I'm getting only `Works`.

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the metaClass of `A` with

```
A.metaClass.invokeMethod { name,args ->
    println "Came here"
}
```

After you construct the `variable`.  If you put this block before the line

```
A varaiable = new A()
```

It should work as you'd expect.

To get round this, you can use:

```
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
```

And instances will check back with the `metaClass` every invocation, however as expected this can slow things down

Comment: Thanks, it works for this case. But what I'm trying is to add intercept calls to `WebElement` (Selenium). But doing the same doesnt work there. Where `WebElement` is an interface.

Comment: It should work if you declare the `invokeMethod` metaclass method on `Bug` **before** you make an instance of `A`...  What version of Groovy?

Comment: Groovy.2.2.0. This is what I'm doing I have a script where I have code like this: `WebElement.metaClass.invokeMethod . . . `. And in the class I call this `script.run()`. So eventually all calls to `WebElement` should be intercepted right?

Comment: Does it work if you add `ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()`? It might be that the web elements are getting constructed earlier than your metaClass addition...

Comment: Thats going as recursion. This is my code. `ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
WebElement.metaClass.invokeMethod { String methodName, args ->
 invokeMethod(methodName, args)
}`. But that goes infinite loop!I'm trying to log the calls and then call the original method again

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125903/groovy-overriding-invokemethod-for-a-single-instance