# Get testname in Integration test

Tags: grails, groovy

In my grails integration test, how do I get the the currently executing test name?

I want to do this for logging purposes.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103495/find-out-a-methods-name-in-groovy

Answer (score 3):

Use JUnit's `@Rule TestName`.  This works with old style JUnit tests and spock specs.

Example:

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.rules.TestName

class MyTestSpec extends Specification {
    @Rule TestName name = new TestName()

    void "test something"() {
        setup:
        println "running $name.methodName"
        ....
    }
}
```