# Groovy get current methods annotation

Tags: groovy, geb

I created a java interface for my annotation. I am now writing a geb spock test and I would like to print the annotation values so it shows in the gradle report. Is this possible? Here is my test case and let me know if I am doing this wrong

```
class Checkout extends GebReportingSpec {

    @TestCase(someID="12345")
    def "A checkout 3-D script"() {
        // My test steps.....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [StackTraceUtils.sanitize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540678/groovy-get-enclosing-functions-name) to get the current method and use reflection to iterate through the annotations:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*

import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils

class Checkout {
  @TestCase(someID="12345")
  def "yeah a"() {
    printTestCaseId()
    // My test steps.....
  }

  def printTestCaseId() {
    def stack = StackTraceUtils.sanitize(new Throwable()).stackTrace[1]
    def method = getClass().declaredMethods.find { it.name == stack.methodName }
    println method
    def someID = method.annotations[0].someID()
    println someID
    assert someID == "12345"
  }

}

@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface TestCase { String someID() }

co = new Checkout()
co."${'yeah a'}"()
```

The `StackTraceUtils` is not needed if you are the one iterating through the methods.

Comment: Is the @Retention stuff a replacement for my annotation code?

Comment: No. I wrote it to reproduce your `@TestCase` annotation

Comment: ok, when I put your code above beyond the @retention lines, I am getting groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: error

Answer (score 0):

spockframework (version "spock-core-1.1-groovy-2.4") is provides way of accessing annotation:

```
package com.test.integration.spec

import com.test.integration.annotation.Scenario
import com.test.integration.annotation.TestCase

import spock.lang.Specification

@Scenario("AnnotationSpec")
class AnnotationSpec extends Specification {

    String scenario
    String test_case

    def setup() {
        scenario = specificationContext.currentSpec.getAnnotation(Scenario).value()
        test_case = specificationContext.currentFeature.featureMethod.getAnnotation(TestCase).value()
    }

    @TestCase("case-001")
    def 'spock provides way of accessing annotation'(){

        expect:
        "AnnotationSpec" == scenario
        "case-001" == test_case
    }

}
```