# Are Runtime Exceptions thrown even when they have been caught?

Tags: java

I have a method which writes in database but if it is not able to write in database then I catch it as `Runtime` exception using `Exception Class`.

```
public fun()
{
  try
  {
        writeInDb(....);
  }
  catch(Exception E)
  {
       //log the event
  }
}
```

Now I have another function calling this function `fun()` but it also catches exception and based on outcome it sends message to client whether successful or not. e.g.:

```
funA()
{
   try
   {
      fun();
   }
   catch(Exception E)
   {
       //send message to user
   }
}
```

I have a doubt here that since in `fun()` I have caught the runtime exception so will `funA` be able to know that an exception has occurred, so that it may send right message.

Comment: `funA()` will only see the exception if you let `fun()` rethrow it after catching it. This is something you could have easily tried with a few lines code...

Comment: It's not `Exception Class`, it's `Exception variable`. `Exception` here is the class that subclasses `Throwable` that you want to catch. If you only want to catch RuntimeExceptions, use `catch (RuntimeException e)`

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I think SIGSTP's *Runtime Exceptions* means runtime-error, opposite of compile-error.

Comment: I understood it as the only Exception that is wanted to catch here is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html . But ok, I might be wrong there. But `E` is still a variable and not a class and should according to the coding standards be written lowercase.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - Technically, that's "coding conventions", unless you work inside an organization that has declared them as "standards".

Comment: @HotLicks True. Sorry, wrong word :)

Answer (score 2):

if you caught the exception in fun(), funA() wont be able to recognize it. It would be able to catch it if fun() throws it

Answer (score 2):

**No** exceptions (runtime or checked) are re-thrown if you **catch it and handle it**.

Once an exception is caught in a method then you have to decide whether this method should handle the exception or re-throw it so that the caller can handle it.

Answer (score 2):

altsyset is perfectly right.

I just wanted to add that Exceptions should not be used as a means of data transport. If you deal with the exception in `fun()`, react accordingly! Use `fun()`'s return value to inform `funA()` of the error - or throw a new, meaningful exception if you absolutely must have one.

This isn't only a question of style but of performance - exception handling slows down your program, so you shouldn't throw them around lightly (pun intended). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions) provides some discussion of that, but the consensus seems to be that excessive use of exceptions is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that `funA` will not see the exception that is thrown by `writeDB` because `fun` has caught it.

You *could* rethrow it in `fun`, like this:

```
  catch (Exception e) {
       //log the event
       throw e;
  }
```

However, there's a problem.  If you do that, the compiler will now complain that `fun` needs to be declared as throwing `Exception`.  (And this "infection" is likely to spread ...)

The correct solution is NOT to catch `Exception`. Instead you should catch `RuntimeException`; e.g.

```
  catch (RuntimeException e) {
       //log the event
       throw e;  // Now the compiler knows that the exception is unchecked
                 // and therefore we don't need to declare it in the method
                 // signature.
  }
```

Or better still, catch the explicit subclasses of `RuntimeException` that you are expecting at that point ... or even better still (IMO), change `writeInDb` to throw specific CHECKED exceptions.

The problem with catching Throwable/Exception/RuntimeException is that you often end up catching all sorts of unexpected exceptions that your code can't effectively handle.  It is better to catch the ones you are expecting and let the rest pass through.  If you catch everything there's a good chance that you will end up burying the ones that are actually caused by bugs ... making it harder to debug them.