# Throw and catch an exception, or use instanceof?

Tags: java, performance, exception, instanceof, throws

I have an exception in a variable (not thrown).

What's the best option?

```
Exception exception = someObj.getExcp();
try {
    throw exception;
} catch (ExceptionExample1 e) {
    e.getSomeCustomViolations();
} catch (ExceptionExample2 e) {
    e.getSomeOtherCustomViolations(); 
}
```

or

```
Exception exception = someObj.getExcp();
if (exception instanceof ExceptionExample1) {
    exception.getSomeCustomViolations();
} else if (exception instanceof ExceptionExample2) {
    exception.getSomeOtherCustomViolations();
}
```

Comment: The second is the least bad option presented.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch custom exception classes contains violations(business, validation, etc.) i need handle this one.

Comment: The second one is the best bet, for something that is any good.

Comment: I'd suggest an interface, and I might call it a `Message` - or just use a `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd advise using `instanceof` as it will likely be faster. Throwing an exception is a complicated and expensive operation. JVMs are optimized to be fast in the case when exceptions *don't* happen. Exceptions should be exceptional.

Note that the `throw` technique probably won't compile as shown, if your exception type is a checked exception, the compiler will complain that you must catch that type or declare it as thrown (corresponding to an `else { ... }` clause if you use the `instanceof` technique), which might or might not be helpful, depending on how you want to handle exceptions that are not one of the specific sub-types.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to hear.

Comment: `instanceof` should be faster, but exceptions are not slow and can be optimized by JIT: http://stackoverflow.com/a/299214/1851024.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev In any case, even if `instanceof` isn't faster, it can't be any slower. The best possible optimization of `throw` would result in the same `instanceof` logic.

Comment: If you take a look at my answer and code you will see `try/catch` is faster.  I'm not saying it passes code smell tests, but it is faster than `instanceof`.

Answer (score 14):

Hate to burst everyone's bubble, but using `try/catch` is **faster**.  That's not to say it is the "correct" way, but if performance is key then that's the winner.  Here are the results from the following program:

**Run 1**

- Sub-run 1: Instanceof : 130 ms
- Sub-run 1: Try/catch  : 118 ms
- Sub-run 2: Instanceof : 96 ms
- Sub-run 2: Try/catch  : 93 ms
- Sub-run 3: Instanceof : 100 ms
- Sub-run 3: Try/catch  : 99 ms

**Run 2**

- Sub-run 1: Instanceof : 140 ms
- Sub-run 1: Try/catch  : 111 ms
- Sub-run 2: Instanceof : 92 ms
- Sub-run 2: Try/catch  : 92 ms
- Sub-run 3: Instanceof : 105 ms
- Sub-run 3: Try/catch  : 95 ms

**Run 3**

- Sub-run 1: Instanceof : 140 ms
- Sub-run 1: Try/catch  : 135 ms
- Sub-run 2: Instanceof : 107 ms
- Sub-run 2: Try/catch  : 88 ms
- Sub-run 3: Instanceof : 96 ms
- Sub-run 3: Try/catch  : 90 ms

**Test environment**

- Java: 1.7.0_45
- Mac OSX Mavericks

Discounting warmup sub-runs of each run the `instanceof` method only achieves at best the performance of `try/catch`.  The average (discounting warm-ups) of the `instanceof` method is 98 ms and the average of `try/catch` is 92 ms.

Please note I did not vary the order in which each method was tested.  I always tested a block of `instanceof` then a block of `try/catch`.  I would love to see other results contradicting or confirming these findings.

```
public class test {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
        long start = 0L;
        int who_cares = 0; // Used to prevent compiler optimization
        int tests = 100000;

        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
            System.out.println("Testing instanceof");
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            testInstanceOf(who_cares, tests);
            System.out.println("instanceof completed in "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start)+" ms "+who_cares);

            System.out.println("Testing try/catch");
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            testTryCatch(who_cares, tests);
            System.out.println("try/catch completed in "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start)+" ms"+who_cares);
        }
    }

    private static int testInstanceOf(int who_cares, int tests) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < tests; ++i ) {
            Exception ex = (new Tester()).getException();
            if ( ex instanceof Ex1 ) {
                who_cares = 1;
            } else if ( ex instanceof Ex2 ) {
                who_cares = 2;
            }
        }
        return who_cares;
    }

    private static int testTryCatch(int who_cares, int tests) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < tests; ++i ) {
            Exception ex = (new Tester()).getException();
            try {
                throw ex;
            } catch ( Ex1 ex1 ) {
                who_cares = 1;
            } catch ( Ex2 ex2 ) {
                who_cares = 2;
            } catch ( Exception e ) {}
        }
        return who_cares;
    }

    private static class Ex1 extends Exception {}

    private static class Ex2 extends Exception {}

    private static java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();

    private static class Tester {
        private Exception ex;
        public Tester() {
            if ( rand.nextBoolean() ) {
                ex = new Ex1();
            } else {
                ex = new Ex2();
            }
        }
        public Exception getException() {
            return ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting inconsistent results.  Sometimes one is faster than the other, but not all the time.  If you take a look at the actual times you will see that `instanceof` is slower at first, but after about 3 iterations `instanceof` performs better than `try/catch`.  This may be due to JIT optimizations and may not be representative of real-world applications.  It's hard if not impossible to get accurate numbers in as testbench when the runtime continuously optimizes for highly recurrent operations.

Comment: In fact, if I run in interpreted mode only `java -Xint` then `instanceof` is the clear winner.  However, if I disable background compilation `java -Xbatch` then `try/catch` wins every time.

Comment: It's interesting. Most of the time is taken in `Throwable.fillInStackTrace()`. Then, on the HotSpot Server VM, it is able to turn the simple try-catch into something similar to the if-instanceof (although I can't get that to be *faster*). On the HotSpot Client VM, the instanceof is a little faster, or if you disable stack traces to exclude them from the test, instanceof is 10 times faster. I'm always impressed by the server VM's optimizations, but it's not the default on 32-bit systems so one can't assume it's there. Either way it seems to not matter unless you're throwing millions of them.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly urge you to actually use a plain object to represent your "constraint". Whether a marking interface (e.g. `Message`) or a `java.lang.String` is up to you. Exceptions are not meant to be used as you intend, even if either could be made to work (I would expect the second to be faster, but a premature optimization...).

Comment: This could be a stored error and logic which analyzes exception during multiple constraints checks...

Comment: You are absolutely right. This is bad practice. But unfortunately, we are not living in a perfect world.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use polymorphism by creating an interface for your custom exceptions that contains the getCustomViolation() method.  Then each Custom exception would implement that interface and that method.

Comment: If I could change the code of Obj class, I would not need such tricks. And just to catch the exception.

So, what's the best in performance purposes and code smells?