# Guarded blocks -- notifyAll() vs interrupt()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, locking

This Q looks for verification and/or comments/opinions the following:

The example on [Guarded Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) is as follows:

```
public synchronized void guardedJoy() {
    // This guard only loops once for each special event, which may not
    // be the event we're waiting for.
    while(!joy) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    System.out.println("Joy and efficiency have been achieved!");
}
```

The other end of this code-- the one setting `joy` properly is something like this:

```
public void setJoy2(TheClass t) {
    synchronized (t) {
        t.joy = true; 
        t.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

The above does the "signaling" on joy by the use of `notify()`.

An alternative is managing this "signalling" by `interrupt()`:

```
public void guardedJoy2() {
    // This guard only loops once for each special event, which may not
    // be the event we're waiting for.

    while(!joy) {
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Joy and efficiency have been achieved!");
}
```

and the one setting `joy` and letting the thread waiting for it is:

```
public void setJoy2(TheClass t) {
    t.joy = true; 
    t.interrupt(); 
}
```

I'm looking to make a comparison between the two-- `setJoy()` and `setJoy2()`.

First of all, `guardedJoy2()` above can "hear" both `setJoy()` and `setJoy2()` properly-- can see when `joy` is set and act the way it is expected to(?)
How does `guardedJoy2()` compare to `guardedJoy()`?
It achieves does the same thing as `guardedJoy()`-- i might be missing something, but i'm not seeing a difference in the outcome.  The only difference is that `guardedJoy2()` released the lock of `this` from within the loop, and someone else acquire it before the method terminates for some unexpected results. Setting that aside (i.e., assuming that this is the only place where the use of `joy` and its side effects appear in the code), there's not difference between `guardedJoy()` and `guardedJoy2()`(?)

`guardedJoy2()` responds to both  `setJoy()` and `setJoy2()`. 
It can "hear" from `setJoy()` when it is done, re-acquires its lock and go from there. 
And, it can "hear" from `setJoy2()`-- by receiving the interrupt and thus throwing `InterruptedException` to get out of `wait()`, that's also the end of synch'd statement, checks to see in `while` condition that `joy` is set and goes from there. If the interrupt was from "someone" else and not from the one setting `joy`, gets into the loop again the same way till `joy` is set.

When, `wait()` is invoked and thus the lock of `this` is released in `guardedJoy2()`, 
some other thread can get in by acquiring this lock and do things that are not supposed to be done till `joy` is set and `guardedJoy2()` is supposed to return properly. However, setting this aside (again, assuming this isn't an issue-- the only thing being looked for is seeing that message on the last line of `guardedJoy2()` on the console.) This-- `setJoy2()` can be preferable in cases where other things can be done on the object while it's getting its `joy` set and go from there (in `setJoy2()`, the thread setting `joy` doesn't have to have the lock of the object to interrupt it while `setJoy()` should have that lock to invoke `notifyAll()` on it).

How does `guardedJoy2()` & `setJoy2()` compare to `guardedJoy()` & `setJoy()` above?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going of the assumption that you meant just `notify()` in your first `setJoy` rather than `notifyAll().`

First, it's important to note that if you're invoking `interrupt()` on an expression of type `TheClass`, then `TheClass` is a subclass of `Thread`. This goes [against](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) a number of [-recommendations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-) that state that you should use `Runnable` instances to encapsulate the logic to be run on a thread rather than subclassing the class `Thread`. The [javadoc of `Thread#join(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-) also states

> It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

This is because some implementations of Java use those methods to handle thread logic behind the scenes. If you do not know that implementation logic and use these methods with `Thread` instances, you might get undesired behavior.

Then, and this might warrant some profiling, throwing (creating) an exception is an [expensive operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions), probably more so than [removing a `Thread` from an object's *wait set*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.1). What's more, exceptions should be used for exceptional conditions, not to guide your application logic.

I was going to say that your second example's synchronization order may be incorrect (assuming `joy` was not `volatile`) because the read in the `guardedJoy2` loop might not see the write in `setJoy2`. However, the Java Language Specification states

> If thread T1 interrupts thread T2, the interrupt by T1
>   **synchronizes-with** any point where any other thread (including T2)
>   determines that T2 has been interrupted (by having an
>   `InterruptedException` thrown or by invoking `Thread.interrupted` or
>   `Thread.isInterrupted`)

So you still have visibility guarantees in place.