# Catch statement error code

Tags: java

I was trying to set my program up that prompts the user to enter the values `y` or `n` into a string called `resetValue` which I `try` to pass the value as `char r`. I know there is some errors with the code but I am curious what the error code should be for my `catch` statement should be. If the user enters an invalid value other than `y` or `n`. I was just looking through a list of errors on Oracle website but there are so many I don't know which one is the best fit for this problem.

```
// Prompts the user to reset the program from the beginning if they wish
while(true){

System.out.print("\nWould you like to enter some new numbers? Type (y) or (n): ");
resetValue = input.readLine();

   try {
      char r = resetValue.charAt(0);
      if( r == y || r == Y ){
         break;
      }
      else if( r == n || r == N){
          reset = true;
          break;
      }
   }
   catch (ERROR STATUS HERE) {
        System.out.print("Please type either (y) or (n) on the keyboard.");
   }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for a character literal 'y', 'Y', 'n', and 'N'.

Comment: try/catch are for exceptions. Restrict user input using if/else only.

Comment: Also, it's probably easier to check `resetValue.equalsIgnoringCase("y")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the nature of `readLine`, your code **should not throw any exceptions** save for a run time exception, like `NullPointerException`.  It's not desirable to catch those as those indicate a missed assumption about something with the state of your code (e.g. your input stream has closed somehow).

Omit the `try/catch` block.

Next, if a user enters an invalid option, **give them a chance to correct it**.  All you need to do is put an `else` condition (aside from fixing those character literals) and continue the loop until it can break on valid input.

Snippet:

```
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid input - please enter only Y or N");
}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that I had put that outside and changed that. I will also take out the try catch block. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Inherit Exception class and create your own Exception!

```
public class YourException extends Exception 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  //You need this. Use a random long


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Some message";
    }
}
```

Comment: But why?!  Why would you want to do this in this case?

Comment: Why wouldn't you? Exceptions are just like any other class you can use at your own convenience.

Comment: But it makes **no** sense to do something like that in this case.  Yes, I'm aware that creating a custom exception gives you more convenience, but in a scenario where only a well-defined run time exception could be thrown, it would make **no sense** to throw a custom exception.

Comment: If there was a well defined run time exception for the case I agree. Which one would it be for this case?

Comment: Exceptions are expensive to throw, and once again, they are entirely unnecessary in this scenario.  Think about the situation again.  The code already has a loop to accept input.  It's already checking if it's one of four different values.  Why would we want to throw an exception there (since [it really is an expensive thing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/299068/1079354)), when we could just fall back to some message?

Comment: Why the downvote? Try Catch are just NOT only for runtime exceptions. They are for values that are not expected in the context. A different value than Y or y is not expected so throwing an exception is perfectly in order and makes code much more readable and structured!!!

Comment: Throwing exceptions is an expensive thing? I disagree. Can you put it in US dollars? Because I can put in US dollars the amount of money that costs when a programmer has to read unstructured code. Also, can you put it in time units? Come on...