# What is "Stack Walking"

Tags: java, performance, stack

It's a phrase I've been hearing a lot recently as I've been trying to improve performance of my application.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729436/4714970) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754873/4714970) for examples of what I mean.

Usually the way it's mentioned is something like this: "It's slow because it involves a `stack walk`"

What does a `stack walk` mean/ what does it mean to `walk the stack`?

Comment: The first half dozen answers when I enter "Stack walk" into google all seem pretty relevant. Any specific question you have that you can't find on google?

Comment: @John3136 could you link me one. I didn't find anything relevant? besides if SO doesn't have an Q/A for it, then it should.

Comment: For any one reaching this question may be interested in : http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/259

Comment: IMHO, we should leave this question open (or make it a wiki entry)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process of Accessing ,Traversal and Filtering of a stack trace can be referred as stack walking. Or in other words we can say that processing a stack trace in any form can be referred as stack walking.A stack trace also called stack backtrace or stack traceback is a report of the active stack frames at a certain point in time during the execution of a program.

Refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) and [OpenJDK Documentaion](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/259) for further details.

Comment: oh okay so it's like a slang thing to say

Comment: @Aequitas Yes is like a slang to denote processing over a stack alike traversal. I hope this answers your question :)