# Scala: Try .getOrElse vs if/else

Tags: scala

I'm a fairly new Scala developer. I am an experienced Java developer and so far I've been enjoying Scala's simplicity. I really like the functional constructs and quite often they force you to write cleaner code. However recently I noticed due to comfort and simplicity I end up using constructs I wouldn't necessarily use in Java and would actually be considered a bad practice e.g.

```
private def convertStringToSourceIds(value: String) : Seq[Integer] = {
    Try(value.split(",").toSeq.map(convertToSourceId(_))).getOrElse(Seq())
}
```

The same code snippet can be written as

```
private def convertStringToSourceIds(value: String) : Seq[Integer] = {
    if(value!=null) value.split(",").toSeq.map(convertToSourceId(_)) else Seq()
}
```

A part of me realizes that the `Try/getOrElse` block is designed with `Options` in mind but quite often it makes code more readable and handles cases you might have missed (which of course isn't always a good thing).

I would be interested to know what is the opinion of an experienced Scala developer on the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not claiming any "experience" title but I much prefer your second construct for a few reasons

- Throwing an exception (an NPE in this case) is expensive and best avoided; it should remain just that, *exception*al
- `if` are expressions in Scala, which avoids declaring "dangling" variables to hold the result of the test (just like ternary operators). Alternatively the `match..case` construct provides for very readable code.
- I would personally return an `Option[Seq[Integer]]` to "pass back" the information that the `values` was `null` and facilitate further chaining of your function.

Something like

```
private def convertStringToSourceIds(value: String) : Option[Seq[Integer]] = value match {
    case null => None
    case _ => Some(value.split(",").map(convertToSourceId(_)))
}
```

note 1: not sure you need the `toSeq`

note 2: for good or bad, looks a bit Haskellish

The combination of Scala + FP makes it almost doubly certain you will get different opinions :)

**Edit**
Please read comments below for additional reasons and alternatives, i.e,

```
def convertStringToSourceIds(value: String): Option[Array[String]] = Option(value).map(_.split(",").map(convertToSourceId(_)))
```

Comment: it is unnecessary to match it, because `Option` does it automatically, just  `Option(value).map(convertToSourceId(_.split(",")))` is needed.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it makes sense. You have several ways to do something correctly in Scala and it can be confusing.

Comment: `Throwing an exception (an NPE in this case) is expensive and best avoided`. I'd stress the importance of **losing** Referential Transparency when using exceptions (via http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223329/side-effects-breaking-referential-transparency), not the *performance effect* (which I interpreted from your usage of *expensive*.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Right, it is best avoided for its potential side effects and as a poor mechanism to handle program control flow. It can also be slow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions

Answer (score 3):

If you can, use `Option`s instead of `null` to show when a value is missing.

Assuming that you can't use `Option`s, a more readable way to handle this could be

```
private def convertStringToSourceIds(value: String) : Seq[Integer] = value match {
    case null => Seq();
    case s => s.split(",").toSeq.map(convertToSourceId(_));
  }
```