# asInstance[T] but with Option[T] as result

Tags: scala

I have instance and type and want to get `Some` in case casting is possible and `None` if not.

Currently I use my own implementation:

```
def tryCast[T](o: Any)(implicit manifest: Manifest[T]): Option[T] = {
  val clazz = manifest.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
  if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass)) {
    Some(o.asInstanceOf[T])
  } else {
    None
  }
}
```

Is there any method in standard library that I can use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no standard implementation of this function. You need to use your own implementation. However, `Manifest` is deprecated, and you should use `ClassTag` instead. Further, when an implicit `ClassTag` is present, the compiler lets you use pattern matching instead of manually checking classes.

```
def tryCast[To: ClassTag](x: Any): Option[To] = x match {
  case thing: To => Some(thing)
  case _ => None
}
```

The above method can also be written as follows:

```
//            "To: ClassTag" desugars to this v parameter, but it has no name
def tryCast[To](x: Any)(implicit tag: ClassTag[To]): Option[To] = x match {
  case thing: To => Some(thing)
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately pattern matching doesn't work because of type erasure.

Comment: I was wrong. `ClassTag` helps.  I need to learn scala better because I have no idea what  `[T:X]` mean.

Comment: 1) When a implicit ClassTag[T] is present, the compiler automatically resolves pattern matching on T with it. 2) T: M in a type parameter means that a implicit parameter of type M[T] is added to the method, without a name.

Comment: @talex `def foo[T: X]` is syntax sugar for `def foo[T](implicit x: X[T])`. X could be known as a "typeclass", which should be a good jumping-off point for googling.

Comment: Note that this only works modulo type erasure. `tryCast[List[String]](List(1, 2, 3): Any)`

Comment: @MichaelZajac of course, a normal asInstanceOf won't catch that either, so it's not any safer than this.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't accept this as answer because I look for standard function (which isn't exist as I understand), but thank you all I understand Scala little better now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of any function like that but you could use `Try` along with `.toOption`:

```
import scala.util.Try
val name: Any = "tyler"
val name: Any = "tyler"
val maybeString: Option[String] = Try(name.asInstanceOf[String]).toOption
val maybeInt = Try(name.asInstanceOf[Int]).toOption

println(maybeString)
println(maybeInt)
```

Output

```
Some(tyler)
None
```

You could take this a step further with an enhanced type with an implicit conversion.

Comment: I look for method, not short expression and if i wrap your code in method it won;t be any better than my.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to catch exception just to check that the object is not of given type.

Comment: Generating and catching an exception is unnecessarily costly for this.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Could you elaborate a little further on the cost associated with throwing an exception?

Comment: An exception is a somewhat large data structure, since it contains a stack trace. In practice I suppose the performance depends on what the JIT decides to do - perhaps it may be clever enough to see that the exception is never used - but why take the chance?

Comment: This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/299315/409976) discusses an exception's impact on performance.

Comment: This may be a case where exceptions are used as part of the control flow (since we can check if casting is possible w/o exceptions), which is [an antipattern](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225/185615)

Answer (score 1):

You maybe want the [TypeTag](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html), like:

```
def tryCast[A](o: A)(implicit tpe: Type, ta: TypeTag[A]): Option[A] = ta.tpe =:= tpe match {
      case true => Some(o)
      case false => None
}
implicit val tag = typeOf[Int]
val cast: Option[Int] = tryCast(1)
val cast2: Option[String] = tryCast("hello")
println(cast)
println(cast2)
```

OutPut:

```
>Some(1)
>None
```

`implicit tpe: Type` is your wanted match `type`, and use `ta: TypeTag[A]` `implicit` `TypeTag` get your parameter type.

for this way, no `cast`, more safe.

Comment: @MichaelZajac, this question wants to check whether parameter type is `T` by `implicit Manifest`, I think it already know which type, it wants to match, Is it right?

Comment: If `o` is `Any`, then you'll get a `TypeTag[Any]`--that's what I mean. For example, `val o: Any = "a" ; tryCast[String](o)` will not work. Comparing type tags only makes sense if a type tag was captured for `o` somewhere else, which based on the OP's signature, doesn't seem to happen.