# Is null pointer exception cause to performance of the android app?

Tags: java, android, performance, try-catch

I am doing one android application, in this app I am creating UI fields dynamically  by local db.  While creating fields based on response from remote server I am getting some null pointer exception due to some fields are not found in db. But, I handle these exceptions by using **try catch** block. Is these exceptions cause to lower performance of app?  If **yes** then give me any other alternatives to handle this.

here is my code-

```
@Override
public void populateField() {


    String value = "";
    try {
        value += DBHelper.getInstance().getDataByID(mField.getId(), 
          refCode).getFieldValue();// **here getting exception**
     .
     ....  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.ex(e);
    }
```

Comment: why not avoiding NPE's by adding Null-checks

Comment: some times it may contain blank string also

Comment: so? the point is that sometimes it contains nothing, and that causes problems, so that's the scenario you need to deal with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **true cost** of using try/catch very much depends on circumstances (mainly the JVM implementation). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions) for example.

Yes, obviously, when you have the *catch* block kick in, quite some CPU cycles will be used for handling it.

But beyond that, Java is simply a language that prefers LBYL over EAPL (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/06/29/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/) for example). Meaning: you *look before you leap*, instead of *asking for foreignness instead of permission*.

These two things **combined** tell you to avoid unnecessary try/catch blocks. In other words: if it is to be expected that "values" are null, then add code that **checks** whether the value is null or not. Use `if`, not `try/catch`!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to use (read, recuperate from end user) the logs on the application, you should note call

```
 Logger.ex(e)
```

depending on the implementation of that logger it might write (or try to write) the exception to a file, which might take some time.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but in debug mode only I am printing error log.