# Workaround to continue process after DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: spring, hibernate

I need to create entity and optionally update it if it's already exist. If I catch `DataIntegrityViolationException` and try to process in `catch` then i'm getting error `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.dating.entities.Complaint entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)`
How to deal with it to process further and update? I can think of TransactionTemplate but looks overcomplicated.
(@Transactional(noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)doesn't help)

```
    @Transactional
    public void create(Entity arg) {
        try {
            eRepository.save(arg);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            eRepository.findExisting(arg.user, arg.reason).ifPresent(e -> //here AssertionFailure error
                    eRepository.save(e.setComment(arg.comment))
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct JPA way to update an entity is to get the entity that you want to update , then change its state and that 's it. No need to call `repository.save()` actually as Hibernate will generate the update SQL to update the entity when the transaction commit if it finds there are state changes in the entities that are loaded in that transaction.

Quote from [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-managed-state) :

> Entities in managed/persistent state may be manipulated by the application, and any changes will be automatically detected and persisted when the persistence context is flushed. There is no need to call a particular method to make your modifications persistent.

So a simpler way is that you first check if the entity exist or not . If yes , update it . Otherwise , create it.

Something like :

```java
@Transactional
public void create(Entity arg) {

     Optional<E> entity = eRepository.findExisting(arg.user, arg.reason);

     if(entity.isPresent()){
        //entity exist , so update the entity
        entity.get().setComment(arg.comment);
     }else {
        //entity not exist, so create it.
        eRepository.save(arg);  
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's similar to solution above. I'd like to find proper way to just update only if there is already existing same record. It doesn't look like something sophisticated. And what if this code is high-loaded? Additional read will affect performance.

Comment: regarding second 'save' - transaction probably aborted and 'save' _probably_ required. When I first wrote the code before testing I haven't used it, hoping for the best )

Comment: for the performance , don't think you need to worry too much at the beginning state . You can add an index in DB table. Together it only involves one record only , it would still be very fast.

Comment: I can even always try delete old record before adding new. My concerns is that I have to work with DB in a different unnatural way due to spring limitations...

Comment: just follow my suggestion and get the job done and move one.  it is very natural . And don't need to over worry the performance .it is a kind of premature optimization. don't make the simple thing become complicated

Comment: Ok, understood, you insist this is inevitable limitation in Spring

Comment: `//entity not exist, so create it.` - that actually does protect nothing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Code like this suffice

```
    eRepository.findExisting(arg.user, arg.reason).ifPresentOrElse(e -> {
        e.setComment(arg.comment); // does your setComment() return `this` ?
        eRepository.save(e);
    },
        e -> eRepository.save(arg)
    );
```

2. [if above doesn't work] Make sure your entity describes primary key (`@Id` annotation), and check if your database contains entities with `null` ids. Normally, primary key should be unique and not null (and database should enforce it)
3. Do not use try-catch to build business logic if possible, it is kind of antipattern

Comment: well, yes, could be like #1, but then it will be always additional read. Although in my case it's not critical but i wanted to find out correct way to deal with such cases.

Comment: about #3 - why try {} catch became intipattern? ) it's powerful construction. Sure, it's not needed in cases where it could be replaced with if-else, but for more complex cases with multiple steps, or where you can't just use if-else without additional i/o - why not?

Comment: @littleAlien in short - I believe additional read is better in 99% situations

Comment: @littleAlien There are some factors, such as - 1. code style - developers intend to use exceptions only for "exceptional situations", in this case, non-existing entity does not clearly denote invalid program state. 2. This way you-re forcing exceptional situation in your database, which will generate confusing false error logs and may slow down database itself when creating a lot of entries. Also, here is a discussion on exception performance itself and many more:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/what-are-the-effects-of-exceptions-on-performance-in-java

Comment: @littleAlien of course it is natural trying to optimize database round trips, but in absolutely most cases, additional single-row select with index scan is no problem. It is maybe worth thinking in case of updates or selecting many rows

Comment: i don't like that framework force me to change code logic in unnatural way...

Comment: For DB's perspective, it is much less natural to force error every time you want to update an entity. DB does not expect from you to try to violate constraints every time, thats why they are called so.

Comment: i don't expect this happen often. and i doubt it's load db more than excessive reads. moreover - what will happen in case of concurrent inserts? it will cause same error anyway... so, nevertheless it force me to change code logic, it's still not correct.