# Convert object variable to decimal with best performance

Tags: c#

I Use following Code for Convert an object value to a decimal.how can i write this code for best performance?

```
decimal a;
try
{
   a=decimal.Parse(objectvariable);
}
catch(Exception)
{
   a=0;
}
```

Comment: What's in the object variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx) method, which forces you to catch an `Exception`, you should use the [static `TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3b1e5ha.aspx) method on the `Decimal` struct.

This will try to perform the parse, and if it fails, return a boolean value determining whether or not you succeeded.  The results of the parse, if successful, are returned through an out parameter that you pass in.

For example:

```
decimal a;

if (Decimal.TryParse(objectvariable, out a))
{
    // Work with a.
}
else
{
    // Parsing failed, handle case
}
```

The reason is this is faster is that it doesn't rely on an `Exception` to be thrown an caught, which in itself, is a [relatively expensive operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164613/why-are-try-blocks-expensive).

Answer (score 1):

i always use `decimal.TryParse()` instead of `decimal.Parse()` Its safer, and faster i guess

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`Decimal.TryParse` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx)

```
decimal number;
if (Decimal.TryParse(yourObject.ToString(), out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
decimal decimalValue = decimal.MinValue;

if(decimal.TryParse(objectvariable, out decimalValue))
        return decimalValue;
else
        return 0;
```

Hope this help.