# Using exceptions to control program flow

Tags: c#, architecture, exception, program-flow

Let me give you an example. I have the following web method inside my aspx.cs file which I use for AJAX calls:

```
[WebMethod]
public static ResponseMessage GetNextQuestion(string quizGuid)
{
    using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
    {
        Quiz theQuiz = Quiz.Get(db, DataValidationHelper.GetGuid(quizGuid));

        try
        {
            Question nextQuestion = QuizHelper.GetNextQuestion(db, theQuiz);

            return new ResponseMessage() { Status = "Success", NextQuestion = new NextQuestionResponse(nextQuestion, theQuiz) };
        }
        catch (QuizNotFoundException)
        {
            return new ResponseMessage() { Status = "QuizNotFound" };
        }
        catch (QuizInvalidException)
        {
            return new ResponseMessage() { Status = "QuizInvalid" };
        }
        catch (QuizOverException)
        {
            return new ResponseMessage() { Status = "QuizOver" };
        }
        catch (QuestionTimedOutException)
        {
            return new ResponseMessage() { Status = "QuestionTimedOut" };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ResponseMessage() { Status = "Error", ErrorMessage = ex.Message };
        }
    }
}
```

The `QuizHelper.GetNextQuestion` method generates a new question from the database and in some specific cases throws the following exceptions:

1. `QuizNotFoundException`: When a quiz with the given `quizGuid` is not found in the database.
2. `QuizInvalidException`: Thrown for security purposes, for example when someone tries to hack HTTP requests.
3. `QuizOverException`: Every quiz has 10 questions and when the user tries to get 11th question using the `QuizHelper.GetNextQuestion` method, this exception is thrown.
4. `QuestionTimedOutException`: You have to answer a question within a given time. If you don't, this exception is thrown.
5. `Exception`: All other exceptions are grouped under this for the sole purpose of informing the user that an error has occured, for UX purposes.

Then inside the Javascript file, the `ResponseMessage.Status` is checked and corresponding action is taken.

I know that using exceptions as they are used in this code to control the flow is bad but making it this way is more intuitive and is much simpler. Not to mention the fact that the code is easier to understand for an outsider.

I am not sure how this code could be rewritten in the "right way" without exceptions but at the same time conserving its simplicity.

Am I missing something, any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Some answers propose using an Enum to return the status of the operation but I have lots of operations and they all may result in different scenarios (i.e. I cannot use the same Enum for all operations). In this case creating one Enum per operation does not feel to be the right way to go. Any improvements over this model?

Comment: Why not have these as objects, like `QuestionResult`, similar to your `ResponseMessage`. It can have a `Status` enumeration representing these possible states; perhaps even a message. Then you'd just have `Question nextQuestion = QuizHelper.GetNextQuestion(db, theQuiz); var response = new ResponseMessage() { Status = nextQuestion.Status }; if (nextQuestion.Exists) response.NextQuestion = new NextQuestionResponse(nextQuestion, theQuiz); return response;`. Then your `try/catch` can catch _truly exceptional_ cases.

Comment: So you propose a mechanism similar to error codes commonly used in C/C++. It feels like this technique is old fashioned but honestly I am not sure, I need to read all answers before I decide.

By the way, why didn't you post this as an answer with a chance of being the answer to the question?

Comment: Not so much error codes (really, you're kinda _already doing that_ as part of your response). If you're invoking a method that can have many reasons for "failing", and they happen often, and they are _expected_ to happen, then yes, if possibly you should consider refactoring it so it gracefully _informs_ you why it couldn't work. (kind of like `Int32.TryParse`, only maybe it'd tell you that it failed because the input was out of range vs bad format). I won't post an answer; the "simplified" [FrankPl's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18520523/1269654) is more or less what I was aiming for.

Comment: You are definitely right about the "you're kinda already doing that as part of your response" part but I am desperate to do so when communicating with Javascript. I would gladly hear the alternative way. Also thank you for the "and they are expected to happen" part, it was quite explanatory.

Comment: Are all these different outcomes used as status of `ResponseMessage`? Then why not make the `Enum` there instead of the strings or maybe with a 1:1 mapping between the different status enum values and their string representation sent to the client?

Answer (score 1):

You would e. g. use an enum `Quiz.Status` and change

```
Question nextQuestion = QuizHelper.GetNextQuestion(db, theQuiz)
```

to

```
Question nextQuestion;
Quiz.Status status = QuizHelper.TryGetNextQuestion(db, theQuiz, out nextQuestion);
switch(status) {
    case QuizNotFoundException:
        return new ResponseMessage() { Status = "QuizNotFound" };
    // ...
}
```

or even simplify that to

```
Question nextQuestion;
Status status = QuizHelper.TryGetNextQuestion(db, theQuiz, out nextQuestion);
if(status != Status.ok) {
    return new ResponseMessage() (Status = status);
}
```

avoiding the long cascade of different cases.

Comment: There are many methods like GetNextQuestion in my project domain and all of these methods can result in many different scenarios. So you basically propose to transform all these methods to Try...(out ...), am I right?

Comment: Yes, similar to the methods in the `.net` framework like `int.TryParse` and `Dictionary.TryGetValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing and handling exceptions are expensive. You are free to throw exceptions when invalid argument is passed or an object is about to enter invalid state, etc. Here it seems you're using exceptions in regular program flow.

Microsoft suggests not to use exceptions to alter the program flow.

> While the use of exception handlers to catch errors and other events that disrupt program execution is a good practice, the use of exception handler as part of the regular program execution logic can be expensive and should be avoided. In most cases, exceptions should be used only for circumstances that occur infrequently and are not expected.. Exceptions should not be used to return values as part of the typical program flow. In many cases, you can avoid raising exceptions by validating values and using conditional logic to halt the execution of statements that cause the problem.

Here is a code analysis [rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264997.aspx)which states that.

So, In your case you need to return some sort of `ErrorCode` as `Enum` or `int`. Will be much better or wrap your `ErrorCode` in `QuizException` in case you feel you need an exception to be thrown here!

**Edit:** Based on your edit, I think you can very much do it. Why creating an Enum or Int as error code is not possible? For instance take an example of `WindowsSocket` which exposes [SocketErrorCodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) holds all kind of socket errors. Or even more appropriate one here is Operating System itself uses Unique [SystemErrorCodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can be wrapped in an `Enum` Isn't it?

Correct me if am wrong or am missing your point!

Comment: Regarding the "some sort of ErrorCode as Enum or int" part, I have updated the question, please notice the last part.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any need here to manage flow via exception (apart *may be* `Exception` and `TimeOutException` ). Remember that exception as itself a heavy enough artifact, and not suitable for fluid control flows and also as name suggests: it's for *exceptional* situations.

There are places where you simply can not avoid exception baced flow, like for example: when you are working with devices. It's a very common command behavior based on exceptions recieved from device or IO.

But, as I said, it doesn't seem to be your case, so just handle it with simple `if/else`, whenever it's possible.

Comment: You say that the use of QuestionTimedOutException might be used but at the same time claiming that exceptions are for exceptional situations. So can timing out be defined as an exceptional situation? If yes, why can't we similarly define QuizInvalidException and other exceptions as an exceptional situation?

Comment: @Anar: Time out is not something that you clearly control (don't know if this is tru in case of OP). Often happens that timeout is raise by some service, come DB request or thing like that. Things that you have no power to control or query state.

Comment: I thought you meant QuestionTimedOutException which is a controllable time interval and which I have power to control. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: any thoughts about using Enum-s or error codes for this purpose? I have updated the question, please notice the last part.

Comment: @Anar: actually yes, you can choose enums, or some other way.The point is avoid using flow with exceptions, whenever it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is "expensive" when a exception is thrown since several calls is done when a Exception is raised.

I would instead recommend a `Question.Status` or `Quiz.Status` that is a Enum.

Edit: For more info [Why are try blocks expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164613/why-are-try-blocks-expensive)